# TypeScript: tuple type to object type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Consider a tuple like this:

```
type MyTuple = [A, B];
```

where `A` and `B` both have an attribute named `key`. For instance,

```
interface A = {
  key: 'sandwiches'
}

interface B = {
  key: 'pasta'
}
```

I desire the following interface:

```
interface Result {
  sandwiches: A;
  pasta: B;
}
```

Is there a way to do this dynamically?

I'm thinking that, if this is achievable, it might look something like:

```
type MapTuple<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K]["key"]
}
```

but this doesn't work.

This question is the *inverse* of [Typescript: object type to array type (tuple)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52855145/typescript-object-type-to-array-type-tuple)

Comment: I think typescript typing is only available at compile-time -- what do you mean with 'Is there a way to do this dynamically?' Do you just want to have the Result interface inferred at compile-time or are you looking for a run-time solution?

Comment: Compile time :) The answer below shows the solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will produce the desired effect. You need to map over all the key properties of the tuple and extract the tuple member for each key :

```
type MyTuple = [A, B];

interface A {
  key: 'sandwiches'
}

interface B {
  key: 'pasta'
}


type MapTuple<T extends Array<{ key: string }>> = {
  [K in T[number]['key']]: Extract<T[number], { key : K}>
}

type R = MapTuple<MyTuple>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working! I'll accept this as the answer in a few minutes, once I'm able to.

Comment: Very nice! Btw `[K in T[number]['key']]: K` this will woks the same as `Extract<T[number], { key : K}>`