# Labeled tuple type to object type

Tags: typescript

I would like to convert this type

```js
type A = [interestID: string, tags: string[], text: string, creatorID: string, createdAt: number]
```

to the following type:

```js
type B = {
  interestID: string,
  tags: string[],
  text: string,
  creatorID: string,
  createdAt: number
}
```

but I have no Idea...Is there any smart way for this?

Note: It is very similar to the following question but it is different that the elements of the pre-converted type is not fixed(changable in each array like `string`, `string[]`, ...).
[TypeScript: tuple type to object type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54599480/typescript-tuple-type-to-object-type)

Comment: Correct. Thank you. But according to this answer, it is impossible to map without specifying each element's key name so I should think of another way of achieving goal.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is any other way - TypeScript doesn't provide an intrinsic way to access the labels in the tuple. However, there is [ms/TS#41594](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41594) which asks to implement one. Until then, this is the best we've got.

Comment: Correction on my previous comment - the issue linked is not asking for a method; it's just a refactoring option.