# How to get object values as a tuple

Tags: typescript

How do I get the type of values from an object as a tuple of those types?

```
type Obj = { a: true, b: 1 }
type ValueTuple<T extends object> = ???
type Test = ValueTuple<Obj> // [true, 1]
```

Comment: There are ways to do this but I would advise against it. What you want is basically to turn a union into a tuple, which is a strange operation, since the tuple is inherently unordered while the tuple is ordered. There is a long gh thread about this https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298

Comment: I meant a union is unordered, while the tuple is ordered. Too late to edit..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that you can get values as types. Even if you could, this is a bad idea. This previously answered question, [How to transform union type to tuple type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type) is a far better answer than I could give :)