# Create a type that is an array of an object properties

Tags: typescript

So I'm trying to get this behavior:

```js
interface A {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: number;
    prop3: boolean;
}

type PropertyArray<T> = magical code

// PropertyArray<A> should be the same as the type ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3']

const properties: PropertyArray<A> = ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3'];

const fail1: PropertyArray<A> = ['prop1', 'prop2']; // type error
const fail2: PropertyArray<A> = ['prop1', 'prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3']; // type error
```

The point of this code is that if I add a new field the interface A, I also need to include that property to the array. If any of the properties is missing the build fails.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transform union type to tuple type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type)

Comment: The question linked above is applicable here if you operate on `keyof A`.  The caveat there applies here: you can't really rely on the order of keys in an object type.  That is, `{a: string, b: number}` is the same type as `{b: number, a: string}`.  So would you want `['a','b']` or `['b','a']`?  Or do you want `['a','b'] | ['b','a']` (the union of all permutations of keys)?

Comment: yes @jcalz, you are right it's a duplicate, the answers in that link is what i wanted, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transform union type to tuple type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really care about property order then this is essentially a duplicate of [this question about turning a union into a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type) if you define

```
type PropertyArray<T> = TuplifyUnion<keyof T>
```

But hopefully you don't really care about property order, and `['prop2', 'prop1', 'prop3']` would be an acceptable value of `properties`.  In that case, there are two ways I can think of doing this:

---

One is to actually calculate `PropertyArray<T>` as a union of all possible permutations of keys in tuples, as you asked.  This would naturally involve a circular conditional type [which is not currently supported](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980).   I can instead make a definition that supports types with up to some fixed number of properties, like this:

```
type PropertyArray<T> = Tup<keyof T>
type Cons<H, T extends any[]> = T extends any ? ((h: H, ...t: T) => void) extends ((...r: infer R) => void) ? R : never : never
type Tup<U, V = U> = [U] extends [never] ? [] : U extends any ? Cons<U, Tup1<Exclude<V, U>>> : never
type Tup1<U, V = U> = [U] extends [never] ? [] : U extends any ? Cons<U, Tup2<Exclude<V, U>>> : never
type Tup2<U, V = U> = [U] extends [never] ? [] : U extends any ? Cons<U, Tup3<Exclude<V, U>>> : never
type Tup3<U, V = U> = [U] extends [never] ? [] : U extends any ? Cons<U, Tup4<Exclude<V, U>>> : never
type Tup4<U, V = U> = [U] extends [never] ? [] : U extends any ? Cons<U, Tup5<Exclude<V, U>>> : never
type Tup5<U, V = U> = [U] extends [never] ? [] : U extends any ? Cons<U, Tup6<Exclude<V, U>>> : never
type Tup6<U, V = U> = [U] extends [never] ? [] : U extends any ? Cons<U, Tup7<Exclude<V, U>>> : never
type Tup7<U, V = U> = [U] extends [never] ? [] : U extends any ? Cons<U, Tup8<Exclude<V, U>>> : never
type Tup8<U, V = U> = [U] extends [never] ? [] : U extends any ? Cons<U, Tup9<Exclude<V, U>>> : never
type Tup9<U, V = U> = [U] extends [never] ? [] : U extends any ? Cons<U, TupX<Exclude<V, U>>> : never
type TupX<U> = [] // bail out
```

And for your case:

```
interface A {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: number;
    prop3: boolean;
}

const properties: PropertyArray<A> = ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3'];
const fail1: PropertyArray<A> = ['prop1', 'prop2']; // type error
const fail2: PropertyArray<A> = ['prop1', 'prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3']; // type error
```

This works how you want, but is a lot of work for the compiler and could be brittle.

---

A slightly less crazy solution (which is still kind of crazy) is to use a helper function instead of a type alias.  The helper function will only compile if its parameters include each and every key of the relevant object type exactly once:

```
type TupleHasRepeats<T extends any[]> = { [I in keyof T]: T[I] extends T[Exclude<keyof T, keyof any[] | I>] ? unknown : never}[number] 

const propertyArray = <T>() => <A extends Array<keyof T>>(...a: A & (keyof T extends A[number] ? unknown : never) & (unknown extends TupleHasRepeats<A> ? never : unknown )) => a;
```

And then try it:

```
interface A {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: number;
    prop3: boolean;
}

const propertyArrayA = propertyArray<A>();

const properties = propertyArrayA('prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3');
const fail1 = propertyArrayA('prop1', 'prop2'); // type error;
const fail2 = propertyArrayA('prop1', 'prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3'); // type error
```

That works also.  I'd probably use the latter if I had to do anything in production code.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html):

```
type PropertyArray = Array<keyof A>; // 'prop1' | 'prop2' | 'prop3'
type PropertyArray<T> = Array<keyof T>;
```

Comment: keyof is not what I want, this is a duplicate, the answer is here [How to transform union type to tuple type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type), thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need an array of A interface then simply do the following:

`const properties: A[] = [ { 'string', 0, true }, { 'string', 1, false } ];`

Let me know if I understand your question right.

Thanks

Comment: no, what I'm looking for is in this link [How to transform union type to tuple type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type) but thanks anyway :)