# How to map Union type to Tuple of the same length?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to turn this:

```
type UnionType = Variant1 | Variant2
```

into this:

```
type ResultingType = [UnionType, UnionType]
```

If the union has 3 member types, the tuple should have 3 elements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transform union type to tuple type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type)

Comment: @Terry no. The ordering is important in that one. In mine, it has to be arbitrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean "permutation"?

```js
type UnionType = 'a' | 'b'

type UnionPermutation<U, K = U> =
  [U] extends [never]
  ? []
  : U extends any
  ? [U, ...UnionPermutation<Exclude<K, U>>]
  : never

// ['a', 'b'] | ['b', 'a']
type test = UnionPermutation<UnionType>
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwCrmgXigcgIY5QA%20uARjgFAWiSyIoAKEATgLYCuwewycAPDAA0UANJRsMAHziKUKAG0YAXSgQAHsAhwAJgGcFcCADcWS2VAD8Cs3IBcsVRq16oeOCHNXFwgHR-4vExsnNy8fACiagDGADbs2hB8IsJSkjZQ9oYmzFQA9LkK%20DjCOOQqJPKlxbgEZjTQmrrA4nSBLBxcPCgC9GgYkkA)

Comment: This is badass! I'm so glad to be able to accept your first answer.