# How to map Record into Tuple with the same size?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to turn this:

```
type SomeRecord = {member1: any, member2: any}
```

into this:

```
type ResultingTuple = [keyof SomeRecord, keyof SomeRecord]
```

If the record has 3 members, the tuple should have 3 elements, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If we import `TuplifyUnion` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55128956/6587634), then :

```
type ResultingTuple = TuplifyUnion<keyof SomeRecord>
```

However, as mentioned by the author of `TuplifyUnion`, the order of the keys cannot be maintained.