# Type safe array with enum index

Tags: typescript, enums

Is there any way to tell Typescript that I have an array that will be indexed by a given numeric enum? For example I might have this code:

```
enum Animals {
  dog,
  bear,
  cat,
}

const animalColours: string[] = [
  "black",
  "brown",
  "white",
];
```

But if I add an extra animal type I can easily forget to update `animalColours`, which leads to a runtime error. An improvement is to use `Record`:

```
enum Animals {
  dog,
  bear,
  cat,
}

const animalColours: Record<Animals, string> = {
  [Animals.dog]: "black",
  [Animals.bear]: "brown",
  [Animals.cat]: "white",
};
```

Typescript will then detect if I miss any variants. However I do not want to use a `Record` for various reasons that I won't go into here. Is there any way to achieve the same thing with an array? The best I can come up with is to convert the `Record` at runtime, but that sucks because it has a runtime cost, especially because you have to sort them (iteration order isn't guaranteed).

```
const animalColoursRecord: Record<Animals, string> = {
  [Animals.dog]: "black",
  [Animals.bear]: "brown",
  [Animals.cat]: "white",
};

// In fact this doesn't even work because Object.entries() always returns
// [string; string][].
const animalColours: string[] = Object.entries(animalColoursRecord).sort((a, b) => a[0] > b[0]).map(x => x[1])
```

It also means Typescript won't complain about `animalColours[10]`.

Is there a way to get the type safety of `Record<T, U>` but using arrays?

Comment: This essentially  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type, the union in your case is `keyof typeof Animals`. The answer is you might be able to do it but it not very robust.

Comment: Not the same question at all. That one doesn't even involve enums.

Comment: The solution is 95% the same. The only difference is that you need one extra step to first convert your enum to a union which is: `type AnimalUnion = keyof typeof Animals`

Comment: The output isn't even the same. That answer produces an array of the possible enum values. I want an array that can be *indexed* by the enum.

Comment: Ah, apologies, I misread. So then, what kind of safety do you expect other than a constraint on the length? Do you have an example of code that you want to error?

Comment: I think the answer might still be similar to that other question. You just need the types in the tuple to be `string` rather than the enum values. Is that accurate?

Comment: No I want the enum types to be integers so that they can index the array! And ideally I want it to give me an error if it can't prove that the index type is my enum, so `animalColors[10]` would be an error as I said in the question.

Comment: It would be nice if `animalColors[0]` was also an error but I can live without that.