# TypeScript: Positional OR Named parameters in constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, constructor, constructor-overloading

I have a class that is currently taking 7+ positional parameters.

```js
class User {
  constructor (param1, param2, param3, …etc) {
    // …
  }
}
```

I want to convert this into named parameters via an options object.

```js
type UserOptions = {
  param1: string
  // …
}

class User {
  constructor ({ param1, param2, param3, …etc } = {}: UserOptions) {
    // …
  }
}
```

This is fine, except there are a lot of tests that now need to be reworked to change the signature, so I'd like to support both named and positional parameters.

I can make the code support both, but I'm not sure how to get the types in there without writing out all the types twice. Ideally the list of types in my `UserOptions` would become positional parameters in the order they're defined in `UserOptions`.

Is there a way to do something like this?

```js
type UserOptions = {
  param1: string
  // …
}

type ToPositionalParameters<T> = [
  // ??? something like ...Object.values(T)
  // and somehow getting the keys as the positional argument names???
]

type PositionalUserOptions = ToPositionalParameters<UserOptions>

class User {
  constructor (...args: PositionalUserOptions);
  constructor (options: UserOptions);
  constructor (...args: [UserOptions] | PositionalUserOptions) { 
    // …
  }
}
```

Would also consider a solution working the other way around i.e. Positional arguments to named, perhaps this is easier?

Comment: A bit late for you, but VSCode has refactoring support to "convert parameters to destructured object" for functions. This updates usage too.

Comment: @spender oh wow I also have this option in vim via coc-typescript. Thanks!

Comment: Do you necessarily need to overload the constructor? A separate factory function might work just as well.

Comment: Sure, factory function would also work but has the same problem, I want to see if there's a way to avoid repeating the type definitions for each parameter.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things blocking you here.

The first is that the order of properties in an object type is currently *unobservable* in TypeScript, because they don't affect assignability.  For example, there is no difference between the type `{a: string, b: number}` and `{b: number, a: string}` in the type system.  There are [dirty tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type) you could perform to tease information out of the compiler to see if it represents the keys as `["a", "b"]` vs `["b", "a"]`, but all that does is give you *some* ordering when you compile; it's not guaranteed to be ordering when you read the type declaration from top to bottom... heck, it's not even guaranteed to be *the same* ordering every time you compile!  See [microsoft/TypeScript#17944](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17944) for an open issue to ask that there be a consistent ordering.  And see [microsoft/TypeScript#42178](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42178) for an example of a seemingly irrelevant code change which alters the ordering from what is expected.  For now, we can't automatically turn an object type into an ordered tuple in any consistent way.

The second is that the names of arguments in a function type are intentionally *not available* as [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types).  They are unobservable, for similar reasons as with object property ordering: they don't affect assignability.  For example, there is no difference between the function type  `(foo: string) => void` and `(bar: string) => void` in the type system.  I don't even think there are any tricks that could expose such details.  In the type system, function argument names are only useful as documentation or IntelliSense.  You can convert between named function arguments and [labeled tuple elements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements), but that's about it.  See [this comment in microsoft/TypeScript#28259](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28259#issuecomment-671741399) explaining that we can't use call signature parameter names or tuple labels as strings in TypeScript.  For now, we can't automatically turn a labeled tuple into an object type where the keys of the object correspond to the labels of the tuple.

---

You can kind of sidestep both of these issues if, instead of trying to convert an object to a tuple or a tuple to an object, we provide enough information to do both:

```
const userOptionKeys = ["param1", "param2", "thirdOne"] as const;
type PositionalUserOptions = [string, number, boolean];
```

Here `userOptionKeys` is an explicit ordered list of the desired keys in the `UserOptions` objects... the same order as in our manually-created `PositionalUserOptions` tuple.  Now that we have key names, we can build `UserOptions`:

```
type UserOptions = { [I in Exclude<keyof PositionalUserOptions, keyof any[]> as
  typeof userOptionKeys[I]]: PositionalUserOptions[I] }
/* type UserOptions = {
    param1: string;
    param2: number;
    thirdOne: boolean;
} */
```

And while we're at it, we can write a function to convert a tuple of type `PositionalUserOptions` into an object of type `UserOptions` (with an `any` type assertion to free the compiler from having to try to verify it, which it can't do easily):

```
function positionalToObj(opts: PositionalUserOptions): UserOptions {
  return opts.reduce((acc, v, i) => (acc[userOptionKeys[i]] = v, acc), {} as any)
}
```

Now we can write that `User` class, using `positionalToObj` in the implementation of the constructor to normalize things:

```
class User {
  constructor(...args: PositionalUserOptions);
  constructor(options: UserOptions);
  constructor(...args: [UserOptions] | PositionalUserOptions) {
    const opts = args.length === 1 ? args[0] : positionalToObj(args);
    console.log(opts);
  }
}

new User("a", 1, true);
/* {
  "param1": "a",
  "param2": 1,
  "thirdOne": true
}  */
```

It works!  From a type system and assignability standpoint, this is the best you can do.  From a documentation/IntelliSense perspective, it's not great.  When you call `new User()`, the documentation for the multi-param version will give you labels like `args_0` and `args_1`.  If you want those to be `param1` and `param2`, you'll just have to bite the bullet and write out the parameter names twice; once as string literals, and again as tuple labels, since there's no way to convert one to the other:

```
const userOptionKeys = ["param1", "param2", "thirdOne"] as const;
type PositionalUserOptions = [param1: string, param2: number, thirdOne: boolean];
```

Is it worth it?  Maybe... that's up to you.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.1.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBArhApgJwPIAcoEtwGlECeEMAvDANoBE6AhsjQLYCMlANDNXYwExsdQALLMgAmqMIkoBdGDWKhIUANwAoKAXSIYABRAQs2cDQA2AVSRpMOSKQq16zAFwxoyLGADm7ez2dg4DABGKOyCwmISzoEgIMaINGBSqmoaWuYoGIY2ZADeFACSMO4wAKIAHsDGcCKIADwA1oQgAGY6egbWJumWWRDsjQQtsmAE5FIAfLIQKjAw6ppDCBlWeIQQ5PlSUs66+lldFpnW65swAL4qAPQAVHOpMN1H4MS5M7MwPk4uUG6equ8fLgMbh+ALBZD-d5hUTiRBRGJxBKqM4wa6XFQqZpwMDALIfdr7YwAFRAqECACsABQgTAQHYEzpmQ4rSAASmcjxZxByb2QiCgcGQYBgNKgEAAdHyRHBgIhKZSaMBgOwAG7sLCs0iTBVK8hLHrWfBEchYLa2NWyJWs9g5FFyYYEVkqC4YypyYjdGA82YKVwyqAgZCU8UhugeOltPaMzm9VmQ30-f2B6lcjnM2Px56J3HJkPisMR8gx44yAA+kY6RiZy1jXrePqzItptgL4rinkEpBIZCYMAA-LJkOHyAAGGTOdAMqskslUgtx+swX2xRBtkAeFNihezC4uiQAdweFkplBofCYoWQcEQC5uddmnAcLGcp7Yb0fPEozgv7+hEUkziJogzqzGiKhAA)

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do this, but the tools you have to use are discouraged by the TypeScript team and rely on the instantiation order of certain internal types (at least that's what [the issue asking for a union-to-tuple operation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298) suggests).

Still, it was fun figuring it out, so here you go:

```js
// Via https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-707364842
type UnionToTuple<T> = (
    (
        (
            T extends any
                ? (t: T) => T
                : never
        ) extends infer U
            ? (U extends any
                ? (u: U) => any
                : never
            ) extends (v: infer V) => any
                ? V
                : never
            : never
    ) extends (_: any) => infer W
        ? [...UnionToTuple<Exclude<T, W>>, W]
        : []
);

type Head<T> = T extends [infer A, ...any] ? A : never
type Tail<T extends any[]> = T extends [any, ...infer A] ? A : never;

type PluckFieldTypes<T extends object, Fields extends any[] =
  UnionToTuple<keyof T>> = _PluckFieldType<T, Head<Fields>, Tail<Fields>, []>
type _PluckFieldType<
  T extends object,
  CurrentKey,
  RemainingKeys extends any[],
  Result extends any[]
  > = RemainingKeys['length'] extends 0
      ? CurrentKey extends keyof T ? [...Result, T[CurrentKey]] : never
      : CurrentKey extends keyof T
        /* && */? RemainingKeys extends (keyof T)[]
        ? [...Result, T[CurrentKey], ..._PluckFieldType<T, Head<RemainingKeys>, Tail<RemainingKeys>, []>]
        : never : never;

// -- IMPL --
type Args = {
  param1: string,
  param2: number,
  param3: Date,
  param4: number,
  param5: string,
  param6: Date,
  param7: boolean,
  param8: boolean,
  param9: null,
  param10: 'abc' | 'xyz'
}

class CompositeClass {
  constructor(params: Args);
  constructor(param1: string, param2: number, param3: Date);
  constructor(...args: [Args] | PluckFieldTypes<Args>) {
  }
}
```

The inferred type of `...args` winds up being `(parameter) args: [Args] | [string, number, Date, number, string, Date, boolean, boolean, null, "abc" | "xyz"]` and the second constructor gets a red squiggle under it until you add in all the other parameters.

The only thing we can't get is a requirement that names for the arguments match the names of the fields (but that's because labeled tuples don't make their labels accessible at the type level, so you can't read them out of the built-in `ConstructorArguments` or write them in here with `_PluckFieldType`.)