# How to describe an array with string literal union?

Tags: typescript

I have this simple union type.

```
type ItemType = 'type1' | 'type2' | 'type3'
```

My goal is to define an array using this type so that it contains all string literals from `ItemType` in no specific order.

For example, `['type1', 'type2', 'type3']` and `['type3', 'type2', 'type1']` are VALID.

But, `['type1', 'type2']` and `['type1', 'type2', 'type3', 'type4']` are INVALID

I only got so far:

```
const myArray: ItemType[] = ['type1', 'type2', 'type3']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transform union type to tuple type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is an ordered set of fixed types... also known as [Tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-3.html#tuple-types)

```ts
type ItemType = 'type1' | 'type2' | 'type3'

type ItemTuple = [ItemType, ItemType, ItemType, ];

// Valid
const t1: ItemTuple = ['type1', 'type2', 'type3'];
const t2: ItemTuple = ['type3', 'type2', 'type1'];

// Invalid
const t3: ItemTuple = ['type1', 'type2']; 
// Type '["type1", "type2"]' is not assignable to type 'ItemTuple'.

const t4: ItemTuple = ['type1', 'type2', 'type3', 'type4'] 
// Type '["type1", "type2", "type3", "type4"]' is not assignable to type 'ItemTuple'.
```

Typescript playground link: https://tsplay.dev/Nl0j5N