# Converting an Object to an array of KV values

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want to convert an object into an array of Key/Value pairings. For instance:

```
const dict = { foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: "hi" };
const arr = dictToArray(dict);
```

Where `arr` would be transformed into a *type strong* representation that looks something like:

```
[
  ["foo", { foo: 1 }],
  ["bar", { bar: 2 }],
  ["baz", { baz: "hi" }]
]
```

This is quite simple to do from a runtime standpoint but i'm struggling to get the typing to come along for the ride. My implementation of the conversion is:

```
export function dictToArray<T extends NonNullable<{}>>(obj: T): DictArray<T> {
  const out: any = [];

  for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    out.push([key, { [key]: obj[key as keyof T] }]);
  }

  return out as DictArray<T>;
}
```

Where the utility functions/types are:

```
export type DictArray<T> = [keyof T, Pick<T, keyof T>][];
```

I presume what's failing is the definition of `DictArray` and in particular the **Pick** reference. I say this because each tuple in the array does consist of the correct run time data but the second element of the tuple which is the key-value pair is typed as the full object `T`.

In an object assignment I'd map over each prop with a `{[K in keyof T]: V }` type of assignment but I'm not sure what the comparable syntax would be for an array. I'm guessing somewhere in there lies the answer.

> [Typescript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m02RGw)

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done for an array of indefinite length. You can definitely create fixed-length arrays where each element of the array has a definite (an different) type, but I think it would require some kind of run-time typing (which TypeScript obviously doesn't support) for an unpredictable mixed types to be copied from the assorted type in the original object.

Comment: @kshetline it may be ... but it is possible when inferring to an object's keys which are also an unknown length ... it's 6 of one, half dozen of another ... but that doesn't mean that TS supports it I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on with some of the code; `NonNullable<{}>` is just `{}`; you might want to pare this down to a [mcve] so that others don't get distracted with what seems to be unrelated code.  The same goes for `Keys` function (aside: why not `keys`) using a `K` that has no inference site; why not just use `keyof T` directly? Unless you're asking about this stuff it's not clear why it's part of the question, other than it happens to be some of your other code.  In my answer I will probably rewrite these but not explain the rewrites since they are off topic for the question.

Comment: @jcalz `Keys` tells the type system that it is keyof T versus Object.keys(T) which does not. As for NonNullable, I have removed it but it's just that in JS `null` is considered an "object" from a typeof perspective but I guess this doesn't pass through to TS.

Comment: @jcalz both are now removed (including playground link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the desired `dictToArray` function type can run afoul of the problem mentioned in [Why doesn't Object.keys return a keyof type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript), whereby an object types in TypeScript are *open* and values can contain more properties at runtime than are known to the compiler.  This:

```
function keys<T extends object>(obj: T) {
  return Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof T>;
}
```

will work just fine when you pass it an object literal, but have possibly unexpected results if you pass it an instance of a class or interface which has been extended with extra properties.  As long as you are aware of this problem and willing to face the consequences if they arise, great.

---

Anyway, my inclination here for a `dictToArray()` typing would look like this:

```
type DictArray<T extends object> = 
  Array<{ [K in keyof T]: [K, Pick<T, K>] }[keyof T]>;

 declare function dictToArray<T extends object>(obj: T): DictArray<T>;
```

We are making a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) which walks through each key `K` in `keyof T` and generates the [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) `[K, Pick<T, K>]` for it.  If `T` looks like `{x: 1, y: 2}`, this makes something like `{x: ["x", {x: 1}], y: ["y", {y: 2}]}`, which has the property values you want but is still nested inside an object type... so we [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) this object with `keyof T` to get the desired [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `["x", {x: 1}] | ["y", {y: 2}]`.

You can verify that this gives you a reasonable type:

```
const arr = dictToArray(dict);
/* const arr: DictArray<{
    foo: number;
    bar: number;
    baz: string;
}> */
```

Oh, well, that doesn't actually show much.  Let's force the compiler to expand that out:

```
type ExpandRecursively<T> = 
  T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: ExpandRecursively<T[K]> } : T;
type ArrType = ExpandRecursively<typeof arr>;
/* type ArrType = (
  ["foo", { foo: number; }] | 
  ["bar", { bar: number; }] | 
  ["baz", { baz: string; }]
  )[] */
```

So, you can see that `arr` has a type which is an array of strongly typed tuples.  Hooray!

---

Oh, wait, I see that you want this type:

```
[
  ["foo", { foo: 1 }],
  ["bar", { bar: 2 }],
  ["baz", { baz: "hi" }]
]
```

which, aside from the fact that the compiler has no knowledge of the [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) values of the object properties (you let the compiler infer the types so they are widened to `number` and `string` as opposed to `1`, `2`, or `"hi"`)... ugh, I digress.

---

I see that you want this type:

```
[
  ["foo", { foo: number }],
  ["bar", { bar: number }],
  ["baz", { baz: string }]
]
```

which seems to represent the *order* of the entries that come out.  Object property order is technically observable in JavaScript, although it doesn't always behave the way people expect ([Does JavaScript guarantee object property order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)).  But in TypeScript types, object property order is *not supposed to be observable*.  The type `{foo: number, bar: number, baz: string}` is *equivalent* to the type `{bar: number, baz: string, foo: number}`.  There's no type system test you should be doing which could distinguish one from the other.  It is sometimes possible to tease order information out of the type system, but it is a terrible idea because it will be nondeterministic ([How to transform union type to tuple type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type)).

So there's no principled way to ask the compiler to give you the above type as opposed to, say,

```
[
  ["foo", { foo: number }],
  ["baz", { baz: string }],
  ["bar", { bar: number }]
]
```

or any other ordering.  It is within the realm of conceivability that we could make `DictArray<T>` give you the *union of all possible orderings*, but this would scale very badly and probably not be particularly usable even for small cases.  So unless you are [morbidly curious](https://tsplay.dev/mZ82ew) about how to generate that, I won't bother.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgUQI4FcCGAbANCgDzAFMBjGfZIsmKmYgOwBMBnS68gMRxeLgF84AMygQQcAEQABGAE8SAWlIALHNkYBzYiwD06GMGwsJAbgBQZoegblgEBnADWxWSwA8AFTjEC9ZizgIACMAKxoAPgAKYJCALjgPAEpEMzg4KGIYdCgHAHlQmgA6Z1do0OTMAIBBKChMWTcSiCEE8PN+CzkSOAARYHIauoavHz9WQILycLgAXjhB+rckAG0AaThgByaWjwBdeLX8AAV+x098VfDdgWXthN22ix9IWGFrW3s4Jn6YDwgF4beXyMcYxCJlOIJRLxPoDWqLDzTBCpOCkewseAQfTxTAMWSzODLXbmFFCaBwSJohgYpwuQItEosCGJZLItJpLEwQpgdAsZSRW4ufArEr7CYhQWya78XaJcxpDppDJZHKBfRwSq9H4AzyPDpmKk077kAlIMkQeIARnwQUwUHiACYbZgAF7xCTKYASAQkw3wO1QAnG37-eGySLBuVmHQAKlR6P9tRh2rDSxRaXN8QY6BAQWIUHl7Nt9rg2dz+cLaVtbrgGKgmw07WmMZ0nXkfCoYFxTAASmRsixgAA3YjYYbTOYjYH+cU0OAAfkQhPWm1psma93ine7fdIA+Ho+GaweAjg8Q85i6fEGHnbBO3zF3+5HY7cV43AcesbgV-mtVv3RzJEKLLBI5oSMKwgQBapY5nmBYCNcAA+cAgRIxYQUuxZZnBFaIXAKFodWmFINW8R1g2JiISiiREnALYWNGOhwMoQpwNg0GOPgACSLGYEwP4QLWMCiAwGhjj+d7rtkqJqLapCOIJwibAJLBCTArHxuAhj5vG6DYAJ1hMPmGLdj+qgwExFLAMsAAM1wzI5kjgckwABCw6BgJAvACTAQkxgwAYQAA7nGGl8L+G7hVBRneOoICMFyaQGgmUFCXMAaFEIKmRG4vGjCC1SprisjhFEwDxNx0IbBsAR0HU5B5fgoHgfgJUnjM0w2fZsxOWB0ESFGwAtJE5qsiifqEiU+BDjg6DEA5aWFr+nDQasdJzO+DIuMtd6rRAABqc18Jt7YbrN2DzSSaS-qQlTaASyzpoQJCNWgWDYG4+3rbI+D9RAEhlbgz2djQbjvTgX3QUdl3EJBmaweWgb8GVKLEmY+o6MxHiegEwVYgZcB5t4lTALpwXABpGpQYGHEQGAljkpSqWOEO9IarU41pMNFKs3ZDl9S5KTsvG1LwCUBJ8-ZlaizSF3zZLQ7LJa6Miyta0bZJJAbiUMvq4dx0EltcDy8Q13srd90BHMT0i2koNvRgkPfWx-2A+EwN2y9YMQ59+0w-N8PQThSMCKjIuqwIGMWEAA)

Comment: Great solution (but I'm starting to realize that's what I should I expect from you). The ordering isn't a concern for me ... i'd never expect to get an order out of object keys. I added the key as a separate element to aid in some filtering and referencing of the Key/Value.