# How can I convert a type union to a type array in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a type union defined like:

```
type UnionType = "PK_1" | "PK_2" | "PK_3" | "PK_4";
```

I'd like to convert such type union to a type array like:

```
type ArrayType = Convert<UnionType>; // Should be ["PK_1", "PK_2", "PK_3", "PK_4"];
```

How can I make such `Convert` method?

Comment: *"I'd like to convert such type union to an array like"* To an *array*, or to an *array **type***?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transform union type to tuple type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes. I meant type array.

Comment: @jayatubi - Just for what it's worth, it's "array type" (tuple type), not a "type array". "Array" is the adjective, "type" is the noun. Just to avoid confusing people. :-)