# How To Turn Union Into a Tuple In TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, tuples, union

Given a type `'a' | 'b' | 'c'`, if and how is it possible to generate the type `['a', 'b', 'c']`?

Comment: See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55128956/2887218) to the linked question; there is no way to guarantee order of the resulting tuple, since `'a' | 'b' | 'c'` is the same type as, for example, `'c' | 'a' | 'b'` and it's an implementation detail of the compiler what order it uses internally.

Answer (score 4):

`UnionToTuple` convert every union to tuple.
In your case `UnionToTuple<'a' | 'b' | 'c'>` will create `['a', 'b', 'c']` type

```
// UnionToIntersection<A | B> = A & B
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (
  U extends unknown ? (arg: U) => 0 : never
) extends (arg: infer I) => 0
  ? I
  : never;

// LastInUnion<A | B> = B
type LastInUnion<U> = UnionToIntersection<
  U extends unknown ? (x: U) => 0 : never
> extends (x: infer L) => 0
  ? L
  : never;

// UnionToTuple<A, B> = [A, B]
type UnionToTuple<T, Last = LastInUnion<T>> = [T] extends [never]
  ? []
  : [Last,...UnionToTuple<Exclude<T, Last>>]
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=5&pln=5&pc=6#code/PTAEFUDsEsHtICqwJKQC4FMBOBnDBjNOSAHgEFQAfUAIQD5QBeUCgMloCg0BPABwwgx4SVJlwEi8EuAbMAFB1ARQGAB6ZIAExygArpADWkWAHdIoAPyg5AQywBzAFwQAlEwYAGUM8gYAbtgcbmoa2tZ2TqDQkABm2KDIboyeipYJqT7%202ADcHBwgoAAyNjhoqFDE5FS0spw8-EUlZZAVUjJMgsQi6Nh4hJWp4CrqGFo6%20kam5lZyqs7gSZ7eoL4BWBwMIaNhs87RcVhFi6AeqVaFGStZWLn5YK2IsAi6vAA2GOQANDUdANpk3xoAF0uHwBA8kM83h8EN9iqUOvDmg8SAg6LVfgggcNQjpfqtsCClFZfkTlr8kZ8AHQ0iFPF7vEgAUVU%20Feuk0MLhTXRILyoIaQ2YpSw0Xs1UgulerwFAgQHTpUMZMjy%20HgCN08w6AHJMKVtRw1ZAEWhnPLmL9dRh9d9JdKgUA)

P.S.: Found this and many useful typescript generic types in [Typescript challanges](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges)

Comment: I love [the challenges you linked to](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges), had never seen that

Comment: You cannot guarantee that `'a' | 'b' | 'c'` becomes `['a', 'b', 'c']`.  Ordering of unions is an implementation detail of the compiler.  See [this link](https://tsplay.dev/mLRkAw) and see what happens if you uncomment the line with `SomethingElsewhere` in it.

Comment: Did you guys find any solution for fixing the ordering of the unions?

Comment: @NazarHussain there is [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55128956/13781208) to another similar question that kinda working but it is do not recommended to use it.