# How to get keys type as array from interface?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface:

```
interface Example {
  foo: boolean
  bar: boolean
}
```

And I'd like a type that matches `['foo', 'bar']`

I've tried

```
type Keys = (keyof Example)[]
```

This matches an empty array, as it doesn't require all of the keys, just partial.

Is there a way to do this?

If this isn't possible? Is it possible to require a type to have all items in the array?

```
const shouldFail = ['foo']
const shouldPass = ['foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: You [*can*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type), but read the link for caveats.

Comment: Why would this kind of type be useful to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> See [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55127004/438273) that Jared [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70637044/how-to-get-keys-type-as-array-from-interface#comment124870129_70637044).

If control over the order of the keys matters in the array, it is better to define the array and derive the shape of your interface from the array:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=21&pc=2#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgDwIYFsAOAbOBpOBPCGAXhgG0ByAMxBHIBoZyAjJAJ3IF0YlDRIoA3AFgAUFDxo4MAKLJ0WXAWIxxkkJXhzMOfBAEwA9AZUALKaql4QAVxgB3JGCijRFmVoX5ls1NsURSMGsUJjhWDmExCSkfeSkSACU4UFYAEwAeWL98BiYaLEcAPkjRPmhNXywALndK+JgAb1EYGGoQGqhWazg6ZpgWVhrKJAwIHtEAXxKRalYYAAoy2ABrLwBLMAq4gEpGvqX+-OVEOtJVvAjDACo+lrv7+4A9Z5fX577pLBQ4Jxg1+TWwDWUAweBgJh43E25EceHIKmi-WSSGsY00aFYcAgEDW4Bg6gRkkY0FYGwA5vDgI5yLBQjBUXBUioQH8wKlEISpOQslhyAA6PoAORZG3ZCBgOLJYCQUGsmPswJM3BgaDYqDgUDC+I0bnIJPJ8IchGo1jZ+M2up5cH58wA7AAGACsAGZdlcDJMXDMQHNFuByudtVtsgRdk0RC0DnkQBhjh44Gd8BFJkA)

```ts
const exampleKeys = ['foo', 'bar'] as const;
type ExampleKeys = typeof exampleKeys; // the type you want

type ExampleKey = ExampleKeys[number];
type Example = Record<ExampleKey, boolean>;

const example: Example = {
  foo: true,
  bar: false,
};
```

Using this technique also solves a frequent problem: iterating objects in a type-safe way:

```ts
for (const key in example) {
  const bool = example[key]; /*
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Example'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Example'.(7053) */
}

for (const key of exampleKeys) {
  const bool = example[key];
}
```