# Can I enforce property-type uniqueness?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to guarantee that there is not more than one field in T of type P. I am thinking something like:

```
declare function f<T, U extends Unique<T, string>>(t: T);
```

so that

```
f({a : '', b: 0, c: 0})
```

compiles but

```
f({a : '', b: 0, c: 0, d: ''})
```

does not.

I was thinking something from

```
type R = (keyof { a : string } ) ['length']
```

But `R` here is `number` not literally `1`.

*Edit:* I need to be able to specify the type P, such that there is a maximum of one field of that type or subtype.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBjeVN) meet your needs? There are many potential edge and corner cases (e.g., what if one property isn't the same type as another but is a subtype or supertype? ) so I'm hoping you can present any use cases you really care about before anyone goes through the trouble of writing up an answer.

Comment: @jcalz Neat solution. I think you can replace `Omit<T, K>` with just `T` though, since you're excluding K right after

Comment: @jcalz — in my case, I have close control over the set of types being used, so the problems you mention don’t arise.  However, I do need to *specify* the unique type; other types can be used more than once.  I will update the question.

Comment: Ohh okay... let me look at that

Comment: @jcalz [I got it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwI4FcIB4AqUIA9gRwAmAzlAPYBGAVhAMbAA0UACgHxQC8UA3lANoBpKAjhQA1hBDkAZlEwBdAFxR5QhTnyFSrKAH4oAUVx0ANiiIZM65teNmLGSdLmZmgtgo4rrghQF8AKEDLMwBDACdoGRQ4BgRyMRksTQJiMipaBjYACmAVeGQ0LGYSYAjRAHM2AEoVADdyBCIAbmDAmRy+MJUAcl7mShUABih-GrbO7r6BqCGoYeY6GbGJjq6oHqh+wZGlkdWWoA) but since you did the hard work, feel free to submit it as the answer so I can give you proper credit.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wX72LW) work then?  Go through whatever use cases you care about and let me know.

Comment: I'm a bit worried about weird edge cases like `f({a: Math.random()<0.5 ? "": 0, b: 1, c: ""})`.  I guess we don't have to worry about those?

Comment: @jcalz — Well in your example, `number | string` is not a subtype of string, so it should be legal.  In my case I am modeling a database table, which has at most one primary key — so the object is a `Record<string, Field>` and one of them is a `PrimaryField`, which is a subtype of `Field`, so all is good.

Comment: I wrote an answer; do note that TS can easily forget properties, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w164XN), since that is part of how structural typing works (`{a: string, b: string} extends {a: string}`) so it's always possible to pass in something with more properties than you expect.  You should consider `Unique<T, V>` a "best-effort" sort of thing, and hopefully harden things at runtime if it really matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `Unique<T, V>` to extend `T` if and only if at most one property of `T` is assignable to `V`, then I think the following formulation does that with a minimum of weird edge cases (although weird edge cases can be very weird indeed, so you should test any edge cases you care about):

```
type ProhibitProperty<T, V> = unknown extends { 
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? unknown : never 
}[keyof T] ? never : unknown;

type Unique<T extends object, V> = { [K in keyof T]: 
  T[K] & (T[K] extends V ? ProhibitProperty<Omit<T, K>, V> : unknown) 
}

declare function f<T extends object>(t: Unique<T, string>): void;
```

The idea: `Unique<T, V>` will ensure that if any property at key `K` is assignable to `V`, no property of `T` other than the one with key `K` is also assignable to `V`.  It does this by inspecting [Omit<T, K>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) which is like `T` but with the `K`-keyed property removed. It [intersects](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) the property type `T[K]` with `ProhibitProperty<Omit<T, K>, V>`.

For `ProhibitProperty<T, V>`, if any of the properties of `T` are assignable to `V`, the output type will be [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), TypeScript's *bottom type* which absorbs all intersections  (i.e., `A & never` reduces to `never` for all `A`).  On the other hand, if none of the properties of `T` are assignable to `V`, the output type will be [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type), TypeScript's *top type* which is absorbed *into* all intersections (i.e., `A & unknown` is `A` for all `A`) .

So when you intersect `T[K]` with `ProhibitProperty<Omit<T, K>, V>`, you will either get `T[K]`, if no other property of `T` is assignable to `V`, or `never`, if any other property of `T` is assignable to `V`.  Oh, and if `T[K]` is not assignable to `V` we just intersect it with `unknown`, since we essentially leave all non-`V` properties alone.

Let's make sure it works:

```
f({ a: '', b: 0, c: 1, d: 2 }); // okay

f({ a: '', b: 0, c: '' }); // error!
//  ~  <------>  ~
// string is not assignable to never
```

Looks good.  The compiler accepts the object literal with one `string` value, and rejects the one with multiple `string` values.  In the error case, it complains about both `string` properties, which is about the best we can do, since there's no principled way in TypeScript to choose a member of a union (although terrible hacky methods exist, see [How to transform union type to tuple type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type) for how to do this and why you shouldn't).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewBYEsBGLjwZOoA8AKgDRQBqAfFALxQCuAdgNYMIDuDUEAHsBAwBMAzlADeAKChSoAbQDSUFJyYQQCAGZRCAXQBcW+dq69+w8lAD89Zqw5R9DCADcIccQF8ZKtZp2Woji5w9tYs7AwA3OLioJBQAKoMKACOdBBExnyCIghoAFYQAMbApJQ0YrIKSlDeGlp6ktKEhlAAZFAAFM1yRjxZZmT+2KgYWIi4BADyALaYRKRyFKVU+oxhHACUHtECRQA2AIZw0OqMxSgInOoZfaY5+UXAFB3A+okpafNQQsBwSgDmFA2+icCBQAii4nUHVEUAO+gA5AjSGh9AAGUiFfQARlIAn0ACYoO4NhEoAB6clQBBMA4gaLQ2HwqBIlHozGIhHE0kUqmuRBwACE4kpUgAflJ8ABaGWyqhQMUiqk-P4Mf6KESsYBwoRCFD-BgHNB7aDABABZyuIA)