# Typescript check that all env variables are set based on interface (union type to tuple type issue)

Tags: typescript

I want `env.d.ts` file to represent required application env variables and make sure that any change or addition to it will result in typescript error as well as runtime error for `checkEnv` function if value is not set.

To do that I create top level file `env.d.ts` file to extend `process.env`:

```
declare global {
    namespace NodeJS {
        interface ProcessEnv {
            PORT: string;
            HOST: string;
        }
    }
}
export { }; // required for declarations to work
```

And include this file in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "include": [
    "./env.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Because of typescript [union to tuple type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type) I found this workaround to do it, but is there a simpler way?

[Typescript sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEDsHsBMFNQA4CdIGNYGcOgC4E8FMBYAKAEtwdYkAzAQ3VAAUV0sBRcAN1AG9TQg0AG0A1rDwAuUBhxIKAcwC602fPALQAH1ABXcHBoVY0AUIAqALQD8quYoDcpAL6k4qADZ0k8Lt8SsmBjS-CRCoLDc0ixoQZxcLqSkIKB0CAgR3LgEmKA0KAC2oAAGkVwAdNDlOBjFpBRUtAzwMWwY8XxmgkwA8gBK5nbqCk5hQgASPQDKgzL2GqPhKWQ0MpAFsDgAFoqgAO5kHh6gAEbwdNBw0LiQJWWV1bX78OCwJjeZGLo%20uFt0OCVUFtYKhRPFivtDscMFtIHsIkgUEhEiRkmAtjgcAhgiAFGRtroTuVUOtgBgKNAfBhIEgtroMMB8IQALQ0TA4YAnDyQE7AAp0ChkyDfdDAHwFSBcWDMimwAAezPJCnA-2%20sAeNVITPgfVgEqlAEkDPKpmRlaqfAAeHonABWIJw5hyAD5QABeTpjQTCADSEidhFAFFA4jwkFWNvtqEdOVS2F4zgicqoBmwupJSGglr9eADsAANHpwKIoHtwM6uqBrBBYFLkV7QNIc3mVKBIw6877-TklKNnKNSJ46FhQABVcA%20Bh-LmwADCw9g7ERNKTKeg2CXSM9ghJ4DUumjNIAFPofEC6DOAGp0Dy6WDSV51gCU26EX0ISCPxXHk-PM9AqALtIAAkvCniC04eLA163rAzjFE%20iygK4JAoaQND6NGZCQOAAHAqC8RHi%20oThNqoAAILpB0HrsHKni6HAlqhuGoC6vqsBGnAcqmuaOBqpa2oscgsRYOUZTOoWADkViSa6oApL0AzaKAkwzJWu6yJkXA5sEFFUdwwhKO6IiVuEkmqeYkn5qZQiSYplk2YIKSSQAGpJCJbsyEBkOgjnyWAUAeSuKxrBs2y7AcRynOclzvDgtylNwGq1JWvZJA2NArkeGkAmUOagCxeUSBgxF%20Sk9LwBgBw4ECHyRF8Pw3scobYPk6xaUW2G4WR3jwMgmCRACwaJdpxUQt4SB0HgflVfitVHkVeClQ24ThIBGDwOZ0yWZIflrQuoB2f0O2vqtZ1CCFR7CW0YkGYtRluo9RaGMY0DLedH2rdsKDwq88KbsexQdH48gXlBoAAESgYtzgQxAkAAhtOAIUhn2rShaNnSck6iKjn0Y5jhh0LoHg4LtK2Y99cI1vCP6wFOYNzguAOfotiH%20bg2CRdCsLwtQW4hdSYU7BokJRWcqSxdc8V3ElVQ1BCXngD5sB%20QTggoShQIgmC3BEQ4QA)

```
// node process types
interface ProcessEnv {
    [key: string]: string | undefined
    TZ?: string;
}
declare var process: {
    env: ProcessEnv
}

// app env types from `env.d.ts`
interface ProcessEnv {
    PORT: string;
    HOST: string;
    // if something will be added to `env.d.ts` we need to ensure that `checkEnv` will show error
}

// https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/remove-index-signature.d.ts
type RemoveIndexSignature<ObjectType> = {
    [KeyType in keyof ObjectType as {} extends Record<KeyType, unknown>
    ? never
    : KeyType]: ObjectType[KeyType];
};

class UnreachableCaseError extends Error {
  constructor(unrechableValue: never) {
    super(`Unreachable case: ${unrechableValue}`);
  }
}

function checkEnv() {
    type AppEnv = Exclude<keyof RemoveIndexSignature<typeof process.env>, 'TZ'>  // PORT | HOST
    const envKeys: AppEnv[] = [
        'HOST',
        'PORT'
        // 'X' error - nice
        // no error if something will be added to `env.d.ts`
    ];

    for (const envKey of envKeys) {
        // use switch to ensure all keys from env union type are present in `envKeys` array
        switch (envKey) {
            case 'HOST':
            case 'PORT': {
                if (process.env[envKey] === undefined) {
                    throw new Error(`Env variable "${envKey}" not set`);
                }
                break;
            }
            default:
                throw new UnreachableCaseError(envKey); // ts will show error if something will be added to `env.d.ts` - nice
        }
    }
}
checkEnv();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your types-only solution!

It does require an extra function to infer a few things for you, however, but  I hope that isn't a big problem.

```
type HasAll<T extends ReadonlyArray<string>> = [T[number]] extends [AppEnv] ? [AppEnv] extends [T[number]] ? T : never : never;
```

Here we check if `T`, an array includes **exactly** the members in the union `AppEnv` with conditionals. The `[]` are there to prevent the conditional from being distributive and to prevent it from being a naked type.

We use this `HasAll` validator in this helper function:

```
function hasAll<T extends ReadonlyArray<string>>(t: HasAll<T>): T { return t as T; }
```

TypeScript is smart enough to infer `T` and pass it to `HasAll`. If it passes the checks, then the type of the parameter `t` is `T`, otherwise it is `never`.

This results in great type checking:

```
hasAll(["HOST"] as const); // error
hasAll(["HOST", "PORT"] as const); // fine
hasAll(["HOST", "PORT", "X"] as const); // error
```

However one limitation is that it does not error on duplicates:

```
hasAll(["HOST", "PORT", "HOST"] as const); // fine
```

Hopefully that isn't a big deal because while it is possible to check if there are duplicates, it's a lot of overhead and complexity for such a small thing.

You can see how this solution works with your use case below:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEDsHsBMFNQA4CdIGNYGcOgC4E8FMBYAKAEtwdYkAzAQ3VAAUV0sBRcAN1AG9TQg0AG0A1rDwAuUBhxIKAcwC602fPALQAH1ABXcHBoVY0AUIAqALQD8quYoDcpAL6k4qADZ0k8Lt8SsmBjS-CRCoLDc0ixoQZxcLqSkIKB0CAgR3LgEmKA0KAC2oAAGkVwAdNDlOBjFpBRUtAzwMWwY8XxmgkwA8gBK5nbqCk5hQgASPQDKgzL2GqPhKWQ0MpAFsDgAFoqgAO5kHh6gAEbwdNBw0LiQJWWV1bX78OCwJjeZGLo+uFt0OCVUFtYKhRPFivtDscMFtIHsIkgUEhEiRkmAtjgcAhgiAFGRtroTuVUOtgBgKNAfBhIEgtroMMB8IQALQ0TA4YAnDyQE7AAp0ChkyDfdDAHwFSBcWDMimwAAezPJCnA-2+sAeNVITPgfVgEqlAEkDPKpmRlaqfAAeHonABWIJw5hyAD5QABeTpjQTCADSEidhFAFFA4jwkFWNvtqEdOVS2F4zgicqoBmwupJSGglr9eADsAANHpwKIoHtwM6uqBrBBYFLkV7QNIc3mVKBIw6877-TklKNnKNSJ46FhQABVcA+Bh-LmwADCw9g7ERNKTKeg2CXSM9ghJ4DUumjNIAFPofEC6DOAGp0Dy6WDSV51gCU26EX0ISCPxXHk-PM9AqALtIAAkvCniC04eLA163rAzjFE+iygK4JAoVqsYAILpB0HrsHKni6HAlqhuGoC6vqsBGnAcqmuaOBqpa2qkcgsRYOUZTOoWADkVhca6oApL0AzaKAkwzEkJDaqJw4YUclrmKukTrmRsAXJA4AeHgGGInQeCWmoijOq6HrCOYwjgLoBRnEgShKIpqYiFhCDxHZ1bCE5Ln2cppnmZZ1m2VWoAKSECJItIwgAEQALJkFguyhsEEWFnhBFER53CFmZFlWdQSjOnZiaNnwoU0uFEV4XIdCvMK2AJZISWgClt5EVlfm5YW6VcPlyEDiQND6NGZDqaAfwYLJHjyV5aaqdA6madpSC6fp8wKEZR44NI4wyXJ5jOk+0gKbwoA+PRSDgLgcZBQ4yESf14CDcNQIgmC3BHi+oThLusiZFwObYB6o3jUewiVuEXFieYXH5qDQgpFxQmQ-mKQFLF5IaCGEglUgGAw4IcMABpQwJYDypVGN4FjOMNksYBQFjQarNSGzbLsBxHKc5yXO8OC3KU3AarUlZ2cOAHqbIiESeENArkeX0AmUOagKRCsSBg7248TegYPAGAHDgQIfJEXw-DexwJXkhQ-UWQ3nVJ3jwMgmCRACwZ879qsQt4i14Bruv4gbR4q3g6vU+EQiAdroDg9MkOSBrn0LlHCNcSE8dh4IKygEeLFtOx3DCEHdlusXRaGMY0Ah+nVdV9sKDwq88KbsexQdH48gXlBoARaBQfOBFECQAC2s4AhSHV+nKHj1XJyTqIY-j5PU+gIYdC6B4G1p+ntdwjW8I-qpf5QfO2tN5+QeIZrNSQuzMI79QW6Z0zmw7OjbPHGcqRc9cPN3PzVQ1BCZkEAyDoA1ovQQKEUJPVBPEN6vUJIpAAOKRGoCArWdAFDwHlHQAoCAoLJAAFQEIEAQ0As5gSgmwNsf4qR2b6BtuTbApEGjUHoIwYodARInDqGEUhjttaUCDLbXQeD4DFGEHQQsJwlA8NAMQ3hoAAAikBMDgC4gCaBog8grmgCIjwID-jEF4cAdCgYtpjSOOYPRmAeg0HHDbS0Zg-r2OGqTJS2ADIaGhmMP6VjRFTRUmpDSWkdJ6U8atbxxkRC+Osb5HKNk7JuIcl2PAGAXHgCUGYNyzjwA20Scmdx0TVZ+KgnE-ymSGzVhiaIysIV76lREFxGKcV0Z1SJk1QisBsyq3SYWappTsr+W6ovOpy4kDhS4hVRa1V6SMMkO0-CzUun9NgGU9qoAck22Gb1YARCSGNT3GqKhfwASmyEY0Nh8B6HDXNvw52QjUihJIfsgAAtg3B+CFHFG+fsqS8Q-ruijhDLiIl4b9EhosUhcsfp-QWoC4Q0cZhEzBQMLiwtsBy0hfsu6D1zplHIc9aggduB-WkExVYQcxqIn2qALgkAyDXA+qQwQ0skBZ2hUHJWFKSWq0rsyoQmds6BDYmUAuPK8BFxLvoMurwK7bn5eEbe9dYCNzGV+Vu3gyAd3gN3Xgvd+5QCHpsUe+zwiT35eam6vD9mAyOH9I0C1LT-NVoWclMLVYLWdMS92qSFqFnxRQ8QSAJZfJ+cY0g8oEA0gBDinADDbUeHteAR1Tiem5NcQUhy4TvGCBWQE3UQT5qhOWsMTipAvVmASgtTa20PAlJsXY9N4BumpN6Rs4p1iy1jE0dQaQR4q2IibB20RL43SujpQy7xNKJ2MrMD2z8A62UixWSGlCQA)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it would be simpler to use an `enum`? The values of the `enum` can be used both at compile-time for typing and at runtime.

```js
enum EnvVariables {
    PORT = 'PORT',
    HOST = 'HOST'
}
```

We can use this to add the both `PORT` and `HOST` to the `ProcessEnv` `interface`.

```js
type EnvVariablesType = {
    [K in keyof typeof EnvVariables]: string
}

declare global {
    namespace NodeJS {
        interface ProcessEnv extends EnvVariablesType {}
    }
}
```

Instead of having an `array` with all environment variables, we can just use `Object.values` to get all enum keys.

```js
const envKeys = Object.values(EnvVariables).filter(value => typeof value === 'string') as (keyof typeof EnvVariables)[];
```

Also the `switch` seems unnecessary.

```js
for (const envKey of envKeys) {        
  if (process.env[envKey] === undefined){
    throw new Error(`Env variable "${envKey}" not set`);
  }
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKA9GAECmB2BuA6AJogLgZ1KOBXAtpAKIIBqAhgE4CW5ARgDbQaQDeoknkACgPIBKAFUgBeSAHI+Q8QBoOXABK8AysLHilq8aAC+2EGgCeAB2jEyVWo2aCTZsexBdIAbQDSkarEgBraIYB7ADNII1Ng83gKGnomDABdAC5IDDQaWABzXX1kaABjBiozDIYAunIGNnlOWHJ8ZmNyPLMAOQDcgCllKqdnLi80aEogprNuSgDmjAwSeBgAD0HYZBZZ6Ks421M2PV7OXd3QCE9l6Hn0LBBQAvJpyABVWEpoJoALWOgAYVvoIkoJygLJYrYj-AKAxycPIBWCpSi4PJocEAClwT3y72sFAYuGgyVg0HgQwAlD1nBhcKZKMiAAaPZ5vD6QPI-ZIAElYaOeeUxTGxuJ0NOJAG55Ad9EE0YjqDDma98j5ZsjSZCuNDYWgYAg3P4WGJeHQAFb5NCIeAVXEYZFrSwfDDExBBagMQbU804+wAPlCdgi7txohE6jhXgy4lJt0gyL8gRCYWgERtMWs9pc8VFVz2kCC4Kj6tSWvgOsMkAicCLupVfS41T61BCyOMEymGEQ5Zc5eL8UDYjRuSdBOQxNV1ecaFeEwA7pACdO-gDabNIObk0xIAAiDmd-w6dczgKajDQNBCjOjyC7ZzikA8hVKkVAA)

---

Edit:

On second thought: Why not make it even simpler and use an `array`?

```
// env.d.ts

const envVariables = ['HOST', 'PORT'] as const

type EnvVariablesType = {
    [K in typeof envVariables[number]]: string
}

declare global {
    namespace NodeJS {
        interface ProcessEnv extends EnvVariablesType {}
    }
}

// other file

function checkEnv() {
    for (const envKey of envVariables) {        
        if (process.env[envKey] === undefined){
            throw new Error(`Env variable "${envKey}" not set`);
        }
    }
}
checkEnv();
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=31&ssc=12&pln=24&pc=1#code/LAKA9GAECmB2BuA6AJogLgZ1KAxge1gzRgQDUBDAJwEtyAjAG2g0gF5IBtAcgAkB5AMoAVLgBpIXAAp8ASiIC6kci3yE02EGgCeAB2iQAomSq1GzIbv3sA3qEj3OAaUjVYkbXrwAzEvAo16JgwOWABXAFs6aEp5eQAuSCIaWABzUABfDWRoHAYqfRSGPDpyBkhbEAdIWHJw5h1yHH0AOTxsgCkBcrsqh1c0aK9G-UlKPCaMDCN4GAAPAdhkFmn-UyCLPXLMyodt7dAIF0XoWfQsEFw8ycgAVVhKaEaAC0DoAGFlaANKMco5haWhh%20eD%20FXsqiSoRwaBBAApQvcci8zBQGKFoAlYNB4NEAJTdHb2DChPSUWEAAzuD2er0gOE%20CQAJNYEQ8cMimKj0elybiANw9PYaLwI6HUAh0p45ADW01h%20LBDi8IMgsIhxDg8Ec0C0kG8vlWrwwCt6Dh6puoPlhOjGEwwiE1HE12q0ilY7sgCOyXlc0GQuMVpqqaCeYwA7tVoBHvr8KdNIPATLSAETM5069LJ6p4YgYaBoXkCwm9bZVIUgdkyuX8oA)

Comment: Interesting idea, I will accept your answer if there will be no other with types only. To make this work I will need to move `env.d.ts` that is not part of app src to `env.ts` and put it to src. In first case any enum extension will not show ts error, second case is nice but I was hoping for top level interface.

Comment: Well I think it's impossible to get any runtime information from a type with pure TypeScript. But there are things like [this](https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys). It requires a transformation of your files with webpack for example though which makes it impractical.

Comment: what I want is that if any change made to env interface type (added, removed, renamed) I will see a ts error in check function, function itself will be typed manually. I see it as a contract saying hey, `env.d.ts` here is all env variables that app required - any change to it should force a change in check function array `envVariables`.