# Typescript convert interface keys to nested tuples/array of strings

Tags: typescript, interface, tuples

Not sure if this is possible... but I am trying to convert an interface to tuples using the keys of the interface.

Interface:

```
interface User {
  _id: string;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  address: {
    firstLine: string;
    secondLine: string;
    state: string;
    zip: string;
    details: {
      active: boolean;
      primary: boolean;
    }
  }
}
```

The new type should allow me to create an array as such:

```
const args: UserKeysTuple = ["_id", ["address", ["zip", "details": ["active"]]];
```

Order does not matter.

Comment: Is any key allowed at any place or is there some kind of hierarchy logic?

Comment: Tuples are ordered, properties are not ordered. So this doesn't really make much sense. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type sepcifically _"You can't rely on the ordering of a union type. It's an implementation detail of the compiler; since `X | Y` is equivalent to `Y | X`, the compiler feels free to change one to the other."_ (This is about unions but relevant because you would have to get the keys from that type, which would be a union)

Comment: The syntax of the `args` example is not valid, you cannot have `:` in an array like that. Did you mean `["_id", ["address", ["zip", ["details", ["active"]]]]`

Comment: @H.B. - Yes! You are right, comma, not colon.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible to some degree using mapped types:

```
type KeyTuple<T> = {
  [Key in keyof T]:
    T[Key] extends object ?
      T[Key] extends Date ?
        Key :
        NestedTuple<T, Key> :
      Key
}[keyof T][]
type NestedTuple<T, K extends keyof T> = [K, KeyTuple<T[K]>];

type UserKeysTuple = KeyTuple<User>;
```

This has some limitations though, among them:

- It's a mess; see also the special case for `Date` because it is an object but usually is treated like a primitive
- This does not check for duplicates, so a key could be listed multiple times without error

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChnID6wAJgFzLphSgDmA3PsjMFFYSHALYQVU0gGTADZx2nHn2p1GBAEaswACxJwAnhQAicSLORwSJKBHToKeAgRZswAGVC9K0wXoKYEAexAl7IR-xkmNzAdf2chS2QAL2AABykBCMsSCBDgYTMcIMtEMGAAN0c5Dw9hCDgQV0tYmi44KA1kYtLyyuyAXyZOztwwNViUAGkINQAVAFdYsoAeUYA+ZABeLIIAbWG1ZFBkAGsRjxhkUYBdMmzR9ZHj5AgAD0hvdGQPOQArCAQwZAB+bIILjbXO4PEhPbSQH5-SwbZBnSKRAByJkgJAmUwgswANMgNgs4fCNrh2qs9moDkdjqtjr1+igkVQIKjJjNRtjBjd7hBHrt9od5ktkOs2SM0Sz1sc5sdGDSBmhMFANuhRShlhtldMMNA5owAPQ6ywAPV+MpQAEFDMZTMqBfSUerNVBsQByAxGEzoJ3a3B6w3GzwgKj6KC0TIOxXW5arABExBIUex0ddlvQ8cFUZisVT0ZSaQyWajuQKECjx1LpcYQA)

Comment: Thanks for this!! It seem to work nice in the playground.

Comment: I'll test it with the application I am working on now... I am sure this gets me closer. My types are a bit weird for the user as they are generated by graphql-codegen.

Comment: Any tips for dealing with a property that might be undefined? Like maybe first_name?: string; in the original user interface?

Comment: Well, what do you want to do with it?