# Interface with defined number of entries in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to create a type that represents an object with a defined number of entries. Both key and the value should be of type `number`.
In theory, I would like to have something like this:

```
type MatchResult = {
  [key: number]: number;
  [key: number]: number;
}
```

The above type represents a match result of 2 teams where the key is the team id and the value is the number of scored goals (this is a good example of usage of such type).

The example above gives an error - you can't define multiple index types.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type dynamic keys with max number of properties in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72182781/type-dynamic-keys-with-max-number-of-properties-in-typescript)

Comment: This isn't something the language officially supports. In the link above you can find some solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know the keys before hand then they can be any number, this means that a:

```
type MatchResult = {
 [key: number]: number
}
```

will work.

If you know the keys before hand you can do something like this:

```
type MatchResult = {
 111: number,
 222: number
}
```

This will allow access like: `a[111]`, but not `a[232]` where `a` is of type `MatchResult`.

But if you want to have a type that has exactly `2` integer keys I don't think that's possible in TS. For one thing it would need to track each object of type `MatchResult` contextually.

You are better off declaring a more specific type, something like this:

```
type TeamResult {
 id: number;
 result: number;
}

type MatchResult {
 host: TeamResult;
 guest: TeamResult;
}
```

Comment: Yea, I guessed that is not supported :/ Thanks