# Generic for convert object to tuple of entries

Tags: typescript

I search method for convert object type, for example

```js
type a = {
   code: 404,
   hello: 'world'
};
```

to entries type that have format of tuple

```js
type TypeA = [['code', 404], ['hello', 'world']];
// or
type TypeA = [['hello', 'world'], ['code', 404],];
```

but still can write only generic that will combine entries elements type in union

```js
type Entries<T> = { [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]] }[keyof T][];
// it's will generate
type wrongTypeA = (["code", 404] | ["hello", "world"])[]; // it is union
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Object.entries`? In this case, it will return `[string, 404 | "world"][]`.

Comment: This is something you probably don't want to do. The order of properties inside of a `type` is not something that can be observed by the type system. To the compiler, the two types `type a = { b: 0, c: 0 }` and `type b = { c: 0, b: 0 }` are identical. There are ways to achieve this, but you should not expect them to work consistently as the compiler might throw around the order of properties in types unexpectedly.

Comment: yes I don't expect that order will saved, all that I want is that result array will have one element of type code,404  and other hello,world   , order can be any, main here is to avoid result of type union[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I have warned you enough about why this is not a good idea. For a detailed explanation why this is a bad idea, see the first answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type). But either way, we can use the `TuplifyUnion` type from the answer to construct our type.

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never
type LastOf<T> =
  UnionToIntersection<T extends any ? () => T : never> extends () => (infer R) ? R : never

// TS4.0+
type Push<T extends any[], V> = [...T, V];

// TS4.1+
type TuplifyUnion<T, L = LastOf<T>, N = [T] extends [never] ? true : false> =
  true extends N ? [] : Push<TuplifyUnion<Exclude<T, L>>, L>

type Entries<T> = TuplifyUnion<keyof T> extends infer U 
  ? {
      [K in keyof U]: [U[K], T[U[K] & keyof T]]
    }
  : never
```

Here is the result.

```
type A = {
   code: 404,
   hello: 'world'
};

type TypeA = Entries<A>
//   ^? type TypeA = [["code", 404], ["hello", "world"]]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAqgOwJYHsEBUUEkEigJwGcoBjEVBAHjgD4YBeYGGACjhigA88EATQmAEMEYGAH5WAawBc8AJQM6ANxRJeMWQihKCCrj36sWMmEgQAzAjCwL6y1bwUSsGmFp35QkWABlBhEAB5c0p0OkZmRApMHDwiUnI0UI5uKD4BYVEJFls6dFd3Ajp9NMMcxVYzS3wYACUnOoLtAmBgAHo2mHQAZQAWADoABgBqL2gYAAUAV0IAC2SS9KERAG0AXQAaGAA1cJgV-sP0Le21gG5Wjq6+-oBGUfBx9CmIABskczAopOOYHwY-v4giEwlsAHIAlboNYpAwCFaFfAwiQgfBTWCycyCV7EcJMGCo9Gw0oCCESdauaZzUIvd6fb5UACinBIrymvCgoS2PhoNG5NFaj1gjNw+CQUEIoT2zzeHy+yCSkigYBQ5i6xVSSyqVnY+IkAG98cxmCsANKmBAwJUqtVwNayFZwM2bLqO50wABkVuVqq6azWRpgAF98Zpmp5WmNYABBAGG40kFAc2S9Qa9DZG2ZQV6vFCyADkAHcUPhXrx88Agxco11vLH6DARajxZLowKrswAHpiVpAA)