# typescript type which is an array of all values of a type with multiple values

Tags: typescript

```
type fruit = 'apple' | 'orange' | 'grape'

type fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'grape']
```

How do I get fruits based on fruit?

Or else how do I do it the other way around where I get fruit based on fruits?

Comment: See [this](https://catchts.com/union-array)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type