# I want to infer the number of keys of an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want to infer the number of keys of an object.

For an array, this works:

```js
type LengthArray<T extends readonly any[]> = T["length"];
type Length = LengthArray<["ryan", 1, true, 90]>;
// Length is 4 :)
```

I'm trying to do this from an object:

```js
type LengthObject<T> = Array<keyof T>["length"];
type Length = LengthObject<{ name: string; age: number }>;
// Length is number :(
```

I would need to know that in the above interface, the number of properties would be exactly 2, not "number".

At the end of the day, what I would most like to know is whether the object has no properties:

```js
type LengthObject<T> = <?>

function infer<T>(o: T): LengthObject<T> extends 0 ? number : string {
    // ...
}
const r1 = infer({}); // r1 is number;
const r2 = infer({ name: "ryan" }); // r2 is string;
```

Comment: One note: I need type inference. The body of the function can be made in several ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detecting if an object type `T` has no keys can be trivially done by checking if `keyof T` is `never`.

```
function infer<T>(o: T): keyof T extends never ? number : string {
    return null!
}
const r1 = infer({}); // r1 is number;
const r2 = infer({ name: "ryan" }); // r2 is string;
```

A general purpose solution to get the number of properties of an object type is a bit trickier. We can distribute over the keys of `T` and build a tuple which has an element for each property in `T`. The number of properties is now the `length` of the tuple.

```
type LengthObject<T, K extends keyof T= keyof T> = [K] extends [never]
  ? []
  : K extends K ? [0, ...LengthObject<Omit<T, K>>] : never

type Length = LengthObject<{ name: string; age: number }>["length"]
//   ^? type Length = 2
```

Note that both of these solutions might or might not behave unexpectedly when index signatures are involved.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQAQKmApgJwDwAqAfABRIBcqBAlJQNZYCeSYVqWAHnFlACYDOqKFgBuuVAH4hEALYAjcZX5wcGAOaoA3qFS7UOLHAg40UCABtzAQlABfUDBTL9ARlQBedJlwlNt6gDcqAD0wa7ogmbyuAEOTnD6AEweXtg4vkIAhjJYlABEOIyZUHmo-kGhSRGoyqpQarEgoKBwjAAOWKgAMjxqcAAWAPJyAFZY8IQANKgA0uxcPAKoDMysBJ4rLFREKQDaMwC689x8grvCYjgHOpKou9cgupRznCdLc1K7AAzTAHT-PXqA2GYwmgxkCDgU1mRCIR0oF1wzRArQ63V6AxSgL6Q1G4yhmiyOSUKnUQUyaly0miODKRF2eXMGP6eQelV0AD0pKjOtjMZ5EkA)

Comment: Hi, can you explain further what `K extends keyof T= keyof T` and `[0, ...LengthObject<Omit<T, K>>]` do?

Comment: Oof, the number of steps to compute `LengthObject` scales *exponentially* with the number of keys, so things will start getting very slow with as few as 8 keys, and blow out the recursion limits completely with 9 or more keys.  You might want to mention that.

Comment: [This version](https://tsplay.dev/N5OM0W) should scale better, although it's doing something [very naughty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55128956/2887218) to work around it.

Comment: @jcalz from my exp, if we  want to know number of props - smth is going wrong