# Adding numbers at type level in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, type-level-computation

Suppose I have this type:

```
type NS = {
    readonly A: 4;
    readonly B: 4;
    readonly Op: 2;
    readonly Cin: 1;
}
```

Then how can I statically know, with a type, that the sum of these ints is 11? I.e.,

```
type S = SumUp<NS> // how to implement SumUp so that S is 11?
```

I am using `ts-arithmetic`, which provides a handy `Add<N, M>` helper type, but I can't seem to find a way to recursively loop over all keys of `NS` and accumulate the results.

Comment: If the keys are static, and there aren't that many, you could use `Add<NS["A"], Add<NS["B"], Add<NS["Op"], NS["Cin"]>>>`. Otherwise, I'm pretty sure you would need to [tuplify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type) a union.

Comment: You could do it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NlDqxN) without the need to tuplify a union but it's incredibly slow, generates a "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite" error, and gets even worse if you have more than 4 keys.

Comment: Using the already mentioned [tuplify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55128956/438273) utility, does something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mq9Xkm) work for you? If so, I can write it up as an answer. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Using tuplify union would look something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wo8paw), but again, there are some risks as jcalz outlined in his answer.

Comment: Wow, great. Writeups as answers would be great, yes!

Comment: @vr. Would you like to provide an answer using the technique in our comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have that many keys, you could always hardcode the adds,

```
type Summed = Add<NS["A"], Add<NS["B"], Add<NS["Op"], NS["Cin"]>>>;
```

otherwise, you may have to convert a union to a tuple, from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type). Here's one such implementation using an accumulator (it's faster because it is tail call optimized):

```
type _SumUp<T extends Record<string, number>, Keys, Result extends number = 0> =
    Keys extends [infer First extends keyof T, ...infer Rest]
        ? _SumUp<T, Rest, Add<Result, T[First]>>
        : Result;
type SumUp<T extends Record<string, number>> = _SumUp<T, TuplifyUnion<keyof T>>;
```

Internally, we "loop over" each of the keys and add the value to the result. Then the `SumUp` type is really just a wrapper around this internal helper, giving it `T` and its keys as a tuple.

If this doesn't fancy you because of the use of `TuplifyUnion` (and all its problems as described in the linked question), you could still do it:

```
//@ts-ignore Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.(2589)
type SumUp<T extends Record<string, number>, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = [keyof T] extends [never] ? 0 : K extends K ? Add<T[K], SumUp<Omit<T, K>>> : never;
```

However, TS will generate an error, which I have not found a way around yet. So I have just resorted to ignoring it since it works for the inputs we give. This method is also a lot slower for TS to compute the result of (it is noticeably slower with a large delay).

[Playground (hardcoded)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgQQCargXzgMyhEOAIhgGcBaAQymBgAsQBTGYAYyIG4BYAKF5gCeYRnAByAZTgBeRLzjy4URpVQQAdgBsBKAFxwALNx4LFy1Zu0AhPYbkKlK9VrgB5MHoBMRkw-POAwsBqegCMRphG-EIi4gCuIEwYMmioADwSANpEyEQAugA0KOjp4lmWeYUpJVluFWKlRIFqeQB8bUYA9B0KAHoA-EA)

[Playground (using TuplifyUnion)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgQQCargXzgMyhEOAIhgGcBaAQymBgAsQBTGYAYyIG4BYAKF5gCeYRnAByAZTgBeRLzjy4URpVQQAdgBsBKAFxwALNx4LFy1Zu0AhPYbkKlK9VrgB5MHoBMRkw-POAwsBqegCMRphGvAD0UXB0MDBgpDoxpDCUrADWEABujFA4GhAA7gB0rARRAI4AroxpwOqkUQCsLSEeAOwADN36UXQl5DAQw1CUaqQ40CDkNWqNasNCjMOjMDVgGquCwvwrcACqC+oAKhAAkmow+aSMrCzqADyHAHzSdgAUh3CMAB43NSoUhwCbaAD8cE+mT0hwAlNJ3jkIMAMHo1Iw8lAEf9AcCodC9EEcPk4BcEVIkSjUAjIRc4OjMfl9sI4AAZShpFw4J6nd5SOzHRbnK43KB3B6LXm-AGMIEgsFwSGfCnvU4MuAYrHvXFy-EqxFQ4mkgBKtLgJo1WuZfB4uxEAAUaqQ6NLdfLQWoBABtAC6ABo4AA1flwb2lCOnQNB32RO0HU6bDTAHACIXPKPs6Tszkwbm816B0TZ72nX0yvEg73WqDlyEwKB1DU4SgaO78uwNpvu-HFyF+jVOl28pMptMnNRPACif1YGhqqEYvMDbNehfZr2iUV4LJEAH1xDUQIcwG7ZR6TfdoKgnmkaGoAOaBtRHgBG+XXAGlGAJSIHL6QNQaPAPYgi+IDvlA2bdB2xgKN+v4VnqVbGlBABiwDiiB574pkP4QDgcCZhGpSoRa9QwL6dgmPIkIHkeJ7LuRaSBmgN4AUBMCBqc3oYVhvprtRNF6BxwFGPacCHsep7qqB5EVFAN53kET6am+H6hvR0lMYmWxjumk54QIBFEWucYSQAGtmUmMRIrxGDECgAHrgkAA)

[Playground (no TuplifyUnion)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgQQCargXzgMyhEOAIhgGcBaAQymBgAsQBTGYAYyIG4BYAKF5gCeYRnAByAZTgBeRLzjy4URpVQQAdgBsBKAFxwALNx4LFy1Zu0AhPYbkKlK9VrgB5MHoBMRkw-POAwsBqegCMRphGvAD0UQACZOTAAOZq0CIAKkIiQaQwlGoslCzqcMCkcIwAHqyMpKTAAG6MzqiMjGBw+RiQdcAARs5BOEG0jAB0ABQeAKwAHACcAJT8WXDiAK4gAKpgADzpFZUwjGqo5QBKjKzQqLu5NGpJADRwapt9jFAAfC8A0ofHU7lADWjAEEBwcAOMlB4Mh6S+0jgAG1YRCoQBdAEnM4otSMJpQLEAfjgAAY4Hp-lVAbj-qS0Ld0sjfhiXhttnsXCBaPs-l8BZTXgTPpEeIJhHAABpIjk7XYSL5GGIKAB6xKAA)

Comment: Very cool! At least two linked problems with `TuplifyUnion` don't apply there: we don't rely on the ordering as adding in any order will work, and unexpected collapsing or expanding will not occur with a union of string literals. I don't know yet if in practice this will be too hard on the compiler. I will ever only have 3-5 members to loop on.