# How to get a new TS type

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am learing TypeScripe, and I am trying to make some util ts types.

For example:

I now have an interface like this:

```
interface Student{
  name: string,
  id: number,
  gender: string
 }
```

and I am need to get the keys to form a new Array type like this

```
type Arr = ['name', 'id', 'gender']
```

so how can I write an util type to make that happen.

Comment: That's a _tuple_ type. Do you just want `keyof Student`, the string literal type? Or something else? How would you use it?

Comment: We definitely need more details and clarity here around what you intend to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55128956. You can also find other solutions here https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298.

In your case, you need to use the `keyof` keyword to get a union of the keys (`keyof Student`), and then you pass it to the `TupleUnion` helper. Keep in mind that the order of the literal values in the union isn't always guaranteed.

https://tsplay.dev/Nr922w

Comment: There's a HUGE DISCLAIMER on the linked answer that this is a bad idea, and there are explanations in there about why.  Please [edit] your answer to acknowledge that this is a bad idea, or that they at least need to be very careful.

Comment: Hey @jcalz, I've been using this approach for some time now, and it works perfectly for string literals. Unfortunately, up until now, there is no easy way to perform this task, you can find other solutions here https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298, but they're all similar... I don't feel the need to acknowledge that this is a "bad idea" since I'm already linking the official solution that already communicates that.

Comment: Show me it "working perfectly" and I'll break it.  [Here is an example](https://tsplay.dev/N7qbBW).  Would you please edit as I asked?  Or is there some principled reason why you won't other than "I don't need to"?

Comment: that's because it creates the tuple starting from the last element in the union, we can't guarantee the order of the tuple, but we can guarantee each element to be declared once. I'll update my answer for a slightly better solution (that starts with the first element in the union).

Comment: yep, I did not know it was this difficult. But this is exactly what I want..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why everyone else is making it into a tuple, union and stuff, correct me if i am wrong but i always do this which looks stupid but simple and never gave me any issues,

```
type A = (keyof Student)[];
```