# Getting the number of types in a union in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to get the number of types in a union type in Typescript, ahead of time? Like this:

```
type unionOfThree = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

const numberOfTypes = NumberOfTypes<unionOfThree>;
console.log(numberOfTypes); // 3

type unionOfFive = 1 | 2 | 7 | 15 | 23;

numberOfTypes = NumberOfTypes<unionOfFive>;
console.log(numberOfTypes); // 5
```

I know it looks like I'm trying to assign a type as a value to a variable, but something like this should at least in theory be possible? Since the number of types in a union is known before compilation.

The reason for this is I want to know if a Set is full, I want to be able to check

```
const randomSet: Set<unionOfThree> = new Set();

...

if (randomSet.size === NumberOfTypes<unionOfThree>) {
  console.log('the set is full!');
}
```

Of course I can just write `if (randomSet.size === 3)`, but when the number of types in the union changes, that number needs to be updated, and therefore leads to a risk for bugs.

Comment: @jcalz I know that exactly what I did is not possible (see the paragraph between the blocks of code in my original post). Now that you say it, I see how can do this with an array, but it's a bit ugly, since the array would be created at runtime, but never used for anything except things that can be known ahead of compilation time.

How would you write a compile time check for that? I assume you mean something like `const foo: NumberOfTypes<unionOfThree> = 3;`, and error if `foo !== 3`? And yes, I can start with a tuple, if that makes it easier.

Comment: How about tuple types instead of unions as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/Nrjl3N)? That has no runtime effect and gives you the behavior I think you want.  Let me know if you want to see that written up as an answer.

Comment: @jcalz Okay, then do it. I started, but realized I don't understand this well enough to write it well. The crucial part here was the bracket notation for tuples (tupleOfThree["length"] results in type 3). Even after seeing it, I can't find it in the official documentation, so I could understand it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start with a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) you'll have a really hard time producing a numeric [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) corresponding to the number of its members in a scalable.  That information isn't directly available, so you'd have to start manipulating the union to get it.  TypeScript really doesn't want to let you observe any kind of order for unions (since `A | B` is equivalent to `B | A`).  So either you will write code that iterates over every possible ordering of your union, which scales badly... *or* you will write code that uses evil tricks, as described in [How to transform union type to tuple type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55127004/2887218), which would potentially be unsupported. It's possible, but best avoided, especially if you have control over where that union comes from.

A much easier approach is to start with a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) which contains the elements of your union in some order.  For example:

```
type TupleOfThree = ["a", "b", "c"]; 
type TupleOfFive = [1, 2, 7, 15, 23];
```

Tuples correspond to arrays of known length and order.  In fact, a tuple type is a special subtype of an appropriate [`Array` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays), which knows about all the methods and properties of arrays like `map()` and `filter()` and, importantly, `length`.  If you had an array of type `TupleOfThree`, then indexing into it with a `number` key should give you a value of type `"a" | "b" | "c"`.  And indeed, we can recover the union you wanted to start with by [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `TupleOfThree` with `number:

```
type TupleOfThreeElements = TupleOfThree[number];
// type TupleOfThreeElements = "a" | "b" | "c"
```

And since tuples are of known length, the `length` property of a value of type `TupleOfThree` will be the numeric literal type `3`.  And indeed, we can recover the size of the union you wanted to start with by indexing into `TupleOfThree` with `"length"`:

```
type TupleOfThreeLength = TupleOfThree["length"];
// type TupleOfThreeLength = 3
```

Assuming that you write your tuple type so that there's one union member per element, and that you don't intentionally break things by writing `["a", "b", "c", "b"]` or `["a" | "b", "c"]` or something, then we can use this approach to very easily give you the behavior you're looking for:

```
const randomSet: Set<TupleOfThree[number]> = new Set();
const size: TupleOfThree["length"] = 3; // okay
if (randomSet.size === size) {
    console.log('the set is full!');
}
```

And if you edit `TupleOfThree` to, say, add a member, you'll get the compile time error to warn you:

```
type TupleOfThree = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]; // added "d"
const randomSet: Set<TupleOfThree[number]> = new Set();
const size: TupleOfThree["length"] = 3; // error!
//    ~~~~ <--- Type '3' is not assignable to type '4'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2&ssl=14&ssc=2&pln=15&pc=1#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-FA2R42byYnIhOoyFFQZ0ZbRkDkhDlq2yACxsnGSoA)