# Convert the properties of an object to function arguments of correct types and position

Tags: typescript

I have a piece of code like this:

```
import { discard } from "../utilities/utility"

export type Arguments<T> = T[keyof T][]

export function useCommand<TObject extends {}, TValue = void>(
  fn: (arg: TObject) => Promise<TValue>,
  onError: (e: unknown) => void = (e) => discard(e),
  onSuccess: (ret: TValue) => void = (r) => discard(r)
) {
  return async (...obj: Arguments<TObject>) => {
    const arr: unknown = Object.assign({}, obj)
    const requiredArgs = arr as TObject
    try {
      if (!!arguments) {
        const r = await fn(requiredArgs)
        onSuccess(r)
      }
    } catch (err) {
      onError(err)
    }
  }
}
```

here is how I use it

```
const func = useCommand(async (arg: {email: string, code: number}) =>{
   // some code 
})


// now elsewhere 
 func("JohnDoe", 2345)

 // this is wrong, one argument mising
func("JohnDoe")

// but this one is right, string|number
func(1, 2)
```

is it possible to have func like this:

```
 func(a: string, b: number)
```

Tried a few things but nothing worked, is it even possible in typescript?

Comment: In short - it's not possible as the object properties aren't positional

Comment: This is impossible as asked; TS does not distinguish types by property order (e.g., `{a: string, b: number}` and `{b: number, a: string}` are the same type).  Even if TS did this, your implementation couldn't work (and you can check that it doesn't) because JS needs to know the keys to use and that information is not present.  The best you can do here is to pass in an ordered list of keys, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wQLVvW). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I ran your code in playground link provided. you should write your answer

Comment: I will do so when I get a chance, might not be for several hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible to implement directly as asked.

Imagine you were to call, for example,

```
const c = useCommand(
  async (x: { a: string, b: number }) =>
    console.log(x.a + " " + x.b.toFixed(2))
)
c("z", 1);
```

[TypeScript types are *erased* upon compilation to JavaScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html#erased-types), so the above code will become something like this:

```
const c = useCommand(
  async (x) =>
    console.log(x.a + " " + x.b.toFixed(2))
)
c("z", 1);
```

How would the implementation of `useCommand` have any idea what keys to use for the `"z"` and `1` arguments?  There's no mention of `"a"` or `"b"` anywhere in that code except for the *body* of the callback function.  And even if you could somehow probe the body of the function in JavaScript, to see that `x.a` and `x.b` imply that the input type needs to be at least of the form `{a: ?, b: ?}`, there's no way to know whether `"z"` goes on the `a` property or the `b` property, or possibly on some other property that happened not to be mentioned in the function.

Your implementation of `Object.assign({}, obj)` certainly doesn't do this; all that does is copies an array into an object, so you turn `["z", 1]` into `{0: "z", 1: 1}`.  That doesn't help... and when you run your example code it ends up behaving like `{a: undefined, b: undefined}`.

Finally, object types don't even maintain a usable property *order* in TypeScript anyway.  So even if the type `{a: string, b: number}` were not erased, that type is identical in TypeScript to `{b: number, a: string}`. It has the same properties, just written in a different order. Indeed, the value `{a: "z", b: 1}` and the value `{b: 1, a: "z"}` are treated the same by TypeScript, and either one would be assignable to either version of the type.  So there'd be no way to understand whether you meant to call `c("z", 1)` or `c(1, "z")`... which is really unsolvable, especially if you ever have multiple parameters of the same type, like `f(0, 1)` vs `f(1, 0)`.

Any attempt to tease property order out of an object type will run into all kinds of weird issues, such as those described at [How to transform union type to tuple type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55127004/2887218).  It's just not a road you want to go down.

---

The only way this could possibly work is to pass in an array of key names into `useCommand`, so both the TypeScript compiler and the JavaScript runtime knows how to match up these keys with parameters.  So the call might look like:

```
const c = useCommand(
  async (x: { a: string, b: number }) =>
    console.log(x.a + " " + x.b.toFixed(2)),
  ["a", "b"]
)
```

If that's okay with you, then the `useCommand()` function could look like this:

```
function useCommand<O extends
  { [P in K[number] | keyof O]: P extends K[number] ? any : undefined },
  const K extends readonly (keyof O)[],
  V = void
>(
  fn: (arg: O) => Promise<V>,
  keys: K,
  onError: (e: unknown) => void = (e) => discard(e),
  onSuccess: (ret: V) => void = (r) => discard(r)
) {
  return async (...args: { [I in keyof K]: O[K[I]] }) => {
    const requiredArgs = Object.fromEntries
      (keys.map((k, i) => [k, args[i]])) as unknown as O
    try {
      if (!!arguments) {
        const r = await fn(requiredArgs)
        onSuccess(r)
      }
    } catch (err) {
      onError(err)
    }
  }
}
```

Here we add the generic type `K` corresponding to the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of the `keys` parameter (where `K` has been [modified with `const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) to give the type checker a hint that you care about the exact order and contents of the `keys` parameter, so it doesn't get inferred as the useless `string[]` type).  And we constrain both the object type `O` and the type `K` so that they match up with each other; if you include a key in `K` that isn't present in `O` or vice versa you should get an error.

Then the implementation also has to change.  The input `args` type is the [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) `{[I in keyof K]: O[K[I]]}` meaning that we replace each key from `K` with the corresponding element type from `O`.

Now instead of `Object.assign({}, args)`, we can use `Object.fromEntries(keys.map((k, i) => [k, args[i]]))` via [the `Object.fromEntries()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).  For each key in `keys` and argument at the same position `i` of `args`, we can create an object entry with key `keys` and value `args[i]`.  And now there's no ambiguity or uncertainty; the first argument goes with the first key in `keys`, and so on.

Let's try it out:

```
// const c: (args_0: string, args_1: number) => Promise<void>
c("z", 1); //"z 1.00"
```

Looks good!  The function type has the right argument types in the right order, and the implementation works at runtime as well.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAjAZwKYGEEFtcCGEAJgDwDyyGAHjBiWsMsgN7IDaACsnCgNLsIYXACMMAJwC6yAD7IA1hgCeCEMnKSAXMm406DZAKGiJ0gPzIiS5NsjEMIXhmLIAvgBomyKEjQxDVLT0xGjI4hgExEgANtYAFIoqauQAlOySnswAasgAvMgAbghwxMAAfHFeIBDacQTiAObaqXllOuJ4cJikWWWZCspo2nz9SACi4h3itRi2EPIQCADuECmthcUu+XEYa7ltOymjEADKYFBQGGhDyHHhMNpZe21FJXm34s8fKcBrLF73MDiFAENBKaC3AB00PqDRubHYAEkeChEqpDFp1OwBIjJNJXF9-sxmD4IH4whgAI5gODhYgAQUaoXy5BEACsMLBISAOrgxhAYOI4FcvMTbok0JDCAAHOIJdw8L7seQK2FodhwPEpNag1DzRYrSyhcii5CC6xEsU8NRxACEtthwnoMDQf1NYtJ5PE7wISwIcH81TuVJpdMZcJ+VuJSDOFyuaDukatrlNrm8BBgUAAFrcJJ9WO7kONJghxDtJknmCmq8AU8BPf4oO90Ng8IQSJVmKDwU24tRtGwCNo-EKIA0FSJtMYxN6Ca1TZ6ENEMJDoggGn3IQRkABqZAAIgPu+Q1EhIkhMAQADE4NRnHEAEza-rsfcEfcK-cifeSX7AAD0-7eL4ja1GqAD6AAMw6Crw46WEy4EAIxTsIM5fJwvJdBgpCvMQZT1nE+4AF4fsgSEpAA3MggEkeRkKQZB+7AEAA)