# TypeScript: Is it possible to extract a random element from a union or intersection of type?

Tags: typescript

Supposing the `abc` type that is an union of the elements `'a', 'b', 'c'`, I'd like to know if is possible to extract any single element from this union, like the example below.

```js
type ExtractRandomElementOfSet<T> = ...

type abc = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

let testType: ExtractRandomElementOfSet<abc>; //=> "b" (or "a", or "c", whatever)
```

I know that is possible to extract the "last" element. I put between quotation marks because if it is a set, then there is nothing to talk about first, second, third... last element.

Comment: The type system should be deterministic. Introducing randomness in type checks would be a really bad idea, no?

Comment: What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: @Bergi maybe. But I just would like to know if that is objectively possible, supposing that all elements having the same type.

Comment: The answer is almost certainly "no", although you'd need to be more specific about what you mean by "random" before we could say anything else.  What on earth would you want to use such a feature for? Without a use case it's very difficult to begin to approach this.  If someone earnestly asked you "is it possible to fit a chair in your mouth", you'd probably say "what?" followed by "no", and maybe even "why?"  That's how I feel right now with this question.  Could you clarify to shed some light on this?

Comment: @jcalz I saw a question about converting a union of types into a tuple and I liked the answer.  However, one thing intrigued me: a type was used to always get the "last" element of a union.  Such a type consists of transforming the union of types into an intersection of functions, whose return is each of the types of the union.  After this process, the return of these functions is inferred, in order to return the last inferred element.  It's like an iterator method that has to go through all the items to access the last one.

Comment: As it is a set, there is no way to guarantee that the tuple has the same declaration order as the elements in the union. So, I ask: why the need to create a type with as many inferences as there are elements, to access the "last" element, instead of extracting any element, or extracting the first element, that is, without the There is no need to infer all the elements of the intersection to only take the last one.

Comment: The question is [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type/55128956#55128956). But I understood that there is no way to iterate over elements of a union. :'(

Comment: It is intentionally unsupported to enumerate union members or to observe or even impose any kind of order on them.  If you could pick a "random" element, it would constitute an ordering. They don't want you to do it. You read through the other answer but I guess you didn't understand that it's exploiting *loopholes*. It's convoluted and inefficient because it's not meant to happen at all.  You're asking if there's an easier way to do something you're not supposed to do. The answer is no. Would you like to see this written up as an official answer post?

Comment: @jcalz I understand perfectly.  And now I understand that the "solution" was based on exploiting a loophole.  Thank you very much.  And yes, I would appreciate a formal response if it would help more efficiently to other members who may encounter the same issue, otherwise it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript does not intend to allow you to choose an element from an arbitrary [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) at all, let alone allowing you to choose one "at random".

The supported language features for unions generally only allow you to do "the same thing" to each member, independently.  For example, a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) splits a union into its members, performs some single computation on each member, and then collects them back into a union.  Or you can use [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to iterate union members, perform a single key-and-value computation on each member, and collect them back into an object type.  But you're not supposed to be able to distinguish union members in arbitrary unions in such a way as to discover or impose an *order* on them.

Now, it turns out that there are several *loopholes* in the language that effectively let you choose an element from a union.  The question [How to transform union type to tuple type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55127004/2887218) has an answer that describes how to do it.  But that answer also states, as forcefully as I could do so, that this is *not supported*.  And therefore it ought not to be very surprising that the method for doing so is circuitous and inefficient.

Indeed, if someone asked how they could get an expensive diamond ring from a jewelry store without paying for it, it is quite possible to describe a procedure that does this, but it is going to be more circuitous and inefficient than pushing a "free diamond ring please" button on the side of the building.  So you have to sneak in through the ventilation system from an adjacent business and then disable the alarm system with a keycard you duplicated earlier in the day by distracting the proprietor with a runaway dog, etc., for the same reason: *you're not supposed to be doing that*.

Every time someone has asked for a feature in TypeScript which would allow you to, (directly or indirectly) select a single element from a union, this request has been declined.   Thou shalt not convert a union to a tuple ([microsoft/TypeScript#13298](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298)). Thou shalt not perform an order-dependent "for loop" over unions ([microsoft/TypeScript#44116](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44116)).  Thou shalt not observe the "first" or "last" element of a union ([microsoft/TypeScript#56813](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56813)).  You can break these commandments, but TypeScript isn't going to try to help you do so.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I understood that it is not a good practice to transform a union into a tuple because of the non-guarantee of the order of the declarations, in addition to making no sense, however, in my case I do not want to transform a union into a tuple, but a union into an array where the order is not important. From these considerations, I regret that, as you said, "TS does not intend to allow...", because it should.

Comment: The solution you presented to remove the last element of a union isn't exactly a trick, just as turning a union into an intersection isn't either, because of the concepts of covariance and contravariance.

Comment: The "trick" to exclude any element of a union (if they are all of the same nature, I understand that it should be the last one declared) from a union should be natively supported.

Comment: Again, because we can transform a union into an intersection, and, the from an intersection, because JS supports method overriding, so that `{m1: (a1) => void} & {m1: (a1, a2) => void}` is exactly the same as `{m1: (a1) => void, m1: (a1, a2) => void}`, and, in this case, when we call the method `m1` only the last declared one is considered, which demonstrates that, despite literal objects do not have numeric indexes, they have an order by declaration.

Comment: Sorry for so many comments. I don't know if this is the most appropriate way to respond, or, given the amount of characters, I should post an answer.

Comment: I'm not show how to respond to this either, since SO isn't really meant for back-and-forth discussions, so neither an answer nor a stream of comments is really a good fit.  I disagree with at least some of what you've been saying, or at least think they need clarification, but I am not inclined to engage in an extended discussion here.

Comment: Sorry. Anyway I thank you for everything. To finish I forgot to mention what the [own documentation](https://tsplay.dev/inferring) says `When inferring from a type with multiple call signatures (such as the type of an overloaded function), inferences are made from the last signature[...]`.