# How to turn an object type into a list of name/type pairs at the type level in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, tuples, union-types

Going from a list of name/type pairs to an object type is not particularly challenging:

```
type PropertySpec<K extends string|number|symbol, V> = readonly [K, V];
type UnknownProp = PropertySpec<string|number|symbol, unknown>;
type PropSet = ReadonlyArray<UnknownProp>;
type CreateObject<Props extends PropSet, OutObj extends Record<string|number|symbol, unknown> = {}> =
Props extends []
    ? OutObj
    : Props extends readonly [infer Prop, ...infer Props]
        ? Prop extends readonly [infer K, infer V]
            ? Props extends PropSet
                ? K extends string|number|symbol
                    ? CreateObject<Props, OutObj & Record<K, V>>
                    : readonly [`Bad Key`, K]
                : "Bad props"
            : readonly ["Bad prop", Prop]
        : "Bad prop list";

type Q1 = CreateObject<readonly [readonly ["a", string], readonly ["b", number]]>;
const q1a: Q1 = {a: "foo", b: 3}; // OK!
const q1b: Q1 = {a: "foo"}; // Correctly flags b as missing
const q1c: Q1 = {b: 3}; // Correctly flags a as missing
const q1d: Q1 = {a: "foo", b: 3, c: null}; // Correctly flags c as extraneous
```

Going the other direction, however, has me stumped. It seems like some variant of the classic "DON'T DO THIS" union-to-tuple conversion may be required (see e.g. [How to transform union type to tuple type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type) ; I think this has a number of threads on both SO and the TS github issues). Is this the only path? And am I right to think the caveats for why that path is undesirable m might not apply here (specifically because order is irrelevant)?

As context, this is useful when dealing with tail-recursive conditional types that include mapping over objects. While a tuple can be decomposed and handled one at a time building up an output buffer to implement tail recursion (and thus avoid the 50 stack size limit), mapped types don't seem to be able to handle this cleanly. Transforming an object type into a tuple would allow this, after which the transform back is easy (as seen above).

Comment: Are you looking for something like this [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDeAoKUCGAuKA7ArgLYBGEATgNxpTE4DOwZAlrgOZXoDGOxA9rwBsIGXFQC+KFKEhQA8gmTUA2gGkoLKAGsIIXgDNYAXSg5VAGlirDh8Uu26DMG5KA)?

Comment: No, @jayatubi, that gives a *union* of the tuples, I want a *tuple* of the tuples. That way I can tail-recursively process them and move them into an output aggregator tuple.

Comment: I’m not sure how you can say both “I want a tuple” and “order is irrelevant”.  Tuples have order. Just because you don’t care about the order doesn’t mean that there isn’t one. Can you articulate a reason why the caveats from the other questions don’t apply here? It seems exactly the same; people in those questions often say “I don’t care about the order” also.

Comment: @DavidDurschlag May be then you could try [Union to Tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type) on that result.

Comment: @jcalz -- my goal is to be able to process one property at a time, so my conditional types can be tail-recursive. I don't care *what* order they're processed in. A union would also be fine if there was a way to take its "head/tail" the same way you can with a tuple (`T extends [infer HEAD, ...infer TAIL]`). Another way of saying this is "I want to process each property exactly once, in any order." I know how to do that from a tuple of properties, but not from a union of properties. Perhaps something like `T extends infer A|infer B`? I have no idea how TS would handle that.

Comment: @jayatubi -- yes, I could do that. I even linked that thread in my question. But that thread (and others like it) explicitly call that technique out as dangerous. So I'm looking for another approach (or confirmation it's not dangerous _in this case_) before heading down that path.

Comment: If you are 100% sure that your final output is completely independent of the tuple order, then it might be "okay" to use those techniques. (Which grabs the "last" element of a union, so you could adapt that directly without passing through a tuple) But it's still not supported by TS, so if you run into any problems down the line (e.g., future TS version breaks it), nobody's going to be inclined to help. It's here-be-dragons territory, for the reasons laid out in the other question. Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: see prev comment... "I want to process each property exactly once, in any order." That's what mapped types are for, but it might require refactoring. Without an underlying use case I couldn't say more.  ... "`T extends infer A|infer B`" That doesn't work. The only way I know of to pull a single element out of a union is in the unsupported technique from the other question where we abuse several features to turn unions into intersections into overloads into the last call signature.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz. I think that's my answer. I can post a more full code sample/explanation, but it involves single type aliases that are 100+ lines long, so it's not exactly easy reading.