From an object, extract type of properties
Is it possible to get type
type Values = [number, boolean, string]

from this object?
const o = {
  fst: 1,
  snd: true,
  trd: '',
}

I've tried this, but what I want is types as array, not union type.
type O = typeof o
type Values = O[keyof O]
  // Values = string | number | boolean


While object property order is deterministic at runtime, control over order in the type system is not possible, so deterministic mapping of the value types is also not possible at the current time.

Why, though? https://xyproblem.info/ Properties of object types have no inherent order, so making a tuple type from them doesn't make much sense.

That said, does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type (Note the "DON'T DO THIS" disclaimer about why this is probably not actually what you want to do in real code)

If I'm understanding your question correctly, this code should create a type that goes [number, boolean, string] from the o object.
const o = {
  fst: 1,
  snd: true,
  trd: '',
};

type O = typeof o;

type ValueTypes<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K]
};

type Values = ValueTypes<O>[keyof O][];

const valuesArray: Values = [1, true, ''];

console.log(valuesArray);



ValueTypes does nothing here. O[keyof O] is the exact same as ValueType<O>[keyof O]. 2. [number, boolean, string] is not equivalent to (number | boolean | string)[], though this might be what the OP actually wants.

