# Typescript: convert object property types to tuple

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I am trying to convert the property types of any type `T` to a tuple containing the types of `T` in order.

```js
type A = {
  a: string
  b: number
  c: string
}

type ToArray<T> = [...{[K in keyof T]: T[K]}[keyof T]] // doesn't work...

type ExpectedResult = [string, number, string]
```

I tried using the spread operator but couldn't get it to work.

[Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUCGAuKBnYATgJYB2A5mlAEY4kCuAtlRAZQMY77HkoC+KKUJCgAVAPYwCBDCAA8IgHwIoAbQB0GpCoDSUUlADWEEGIBmogLo4ROi7xVGT5kRYtQA9O6gATMRFwkAOTAUADuYgQGGmoCQtAAogAekGzAEN4ASv50ADYhiCpcpGQANFD0TCxlReQWQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been covered in the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68695508/10311008). Please be warned that doing this is not the best idea, and the reasons why are listed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55128956/10311008).

Taking it back to your use-case, you would use the code from the first answer as follows:

```
type A = {
  a: string
  b: number
  c: string
}

type ExpectedResult = ObjValueTuple<A>
```

Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHsAtQI3BPUATcA7A5AF2eUnICWAzgFCbwAOApqAKqoFoAq4AkqplQE5FUDGmRqgA8tAHygAvCVCgAFLVBUAHp1RIioAIapEAfnkBrAFx0AlFIkA3cASShTqKle4WVajfLknQBVADNuUFYLSWtbJAsDVgdQJxcuMkoaABktIkwAeX9hJglpWXohFnZOHn5BNFylVSp1TR19eVCJJlj47gl3Os85Fvk-QK5QACUo0fbnbhISEFAmAGUAFgA6AAYAaiTqUAAFAFciSGru%20u1dAG0AXQAaUAA1fNALldemO-urgG4ZucXVgCMW3IOyY%20woABsCP54EUqu9QCkpIj0lkcnk7gA5ZEXJhXGoeTQXDpcfEGTBcfY0Uz%20LQQ3j5GR4Sk0U6ebEGa6xA5HXLgqEwuEiACiyj4EP2SCouTuKTEYllYhmIJoWhgfGR6C06FAAB9QOgYDr9eg%20Ogfiq8MiwZDobCGFU1XwxF9QHMLgAiLQeu4emA%200Aevgeq7K5KgTIwABW9zpVJtEOlCIA0gsCT0Gpd8ZJ5vy7ULhIYqPBwP55gqJmzM-AuTnrozZKn02cLoMgsm7q8Vm3hsm8UyDJGY3GqAmk3c%203cXq8RncmBdk6AAGSgIslst4q5K2SmEa-MAATXA%202GfHAUuMYZ2AEFkQBvJlaUwZLh%20ADmTJgjn2AFsYNNZD4Z8KXfEgAF99zwcNRWoAQqCQEYqCIfYIWwOsX3fO5UF-f8uDuOBwETHRQ0tGCKngxDkNQ5Eh1jCVR35aVryVEggA).